# Is it true that $\gamma_{\lfloor\log\Gamma(x)\rfloor}\sim 2\pi x$?

Tags: number-theory, asymptotics, roots, gamma-function, zeta-functions

I realise that Gram points can approximate the imaginary part on the $x$th zeta zero $(\gamma_x)$ accurately, and indeed, Guilherme França, André LeClair give another formula, namely $$\dfrac{2\pi(x-\frac{11}{8})}{W(e^{-1}(x-\frac{11}{8}))}$$ in [this paper](http://arxiv.org/abs/1407.4358), where $W(x) = $ Lambert W function.

$$$$
I noticed that the parametric plot of $\{\log\Gamma(x),2\pi x\}$ was also very similar to $\{x,\gamma_x\}$.

Approximating the inverse gamma funcion ($\Gamma_1^{-1}$) as per [here](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function#) 
$\gamma_x$ can then be approximated with

$2\ \pi\ \Gamma_1^{-1}(\operatorname{exp}(x-1))-\pi$, and gives a surprisingly good fit, even for very high $\gamma_x:$

[image]
[image]
[image]

ie, $\gamma_x\sim$
$$
2\pi\log\left(\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}(x-1)+\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e}-\Gamma(k)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\bigg/ W\left(\frac{1}{e}\log\left(\dfrac{\operatorname{exp}(x-1)+\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}{e}-\Gamma(k)}{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\right)
$$

where $k\approx 1.461632\dots$

Alternatively, it could be stated $\gamma_{\lfloor\log\Gamma(x)\rfloor}\sim 2\pi x$.

Is there anything different being conjectured here, or is it basically a restatement of the above?

```
k=x/.FindRoot[PolyGamma[x]==0,{x,1},WorkingPrecision->20];
g[x_] := 2 Pi Log[(Exp[x - 1]+Sqrt[2Pi]/E-Gamma[ k])/Sqrt[2Pi]] /LambertW[(1/E)Log[(Exp[x - 1]+Sqrt[2Pi]/E-Gamma[k])/Sqrt[2Pi]] ]
```

## Update

Interestingly, $\dfrac{\gamma_{\lfloor\log\Gamma(x)\rfloor}}{2\pi x}$ appears to converge to $1$ at a similar rate to $\left(1+\frac{1}{\text{const.}x}\right)^{\text{const.}x}\rightarrow e.$

I include a plot of $\dfrac{\gamma_{\lfloor\log\Gamma(x)\rfloor}}{2\pi xe^{-1}}\bigg/\left(1+\frac{1}{0.83 x}\right)^{0.83 x}$ below:

[image]

Comment: At least $9$ edit in 5 hours and $5$ of them in one hour. Can you please stop trivial edit? Thanks.

Comment: Sorry - very tired when first wrote it! - All corrected & checked now - apologies again!

Comment: Not relevant to this, but I noticed that the plot you provided asymptotically mirrors, this function: [link] (http://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=-sin(((-1)%5E(-x)+Pi+(x%2Bx!))%2Fx%5E2)), which is 0 for every prime number, complex for all real numbers that are not integers, and curious for all non-prime integers.

Comment: This follows from $$
x \approx \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{{\Gamma (x)}}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)}}{{W\left( {\frac{1}{{\rm e}}\log \left( {\frac{{\Gamma (x)}}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)} \right)}} + \frac{1}{2},
$$ which is shown [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461207).