# What is the sign and exact value of this sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \tan(\frac{1}{n!})$?

Tags: sequences-and-series, trigonometry, convergence-divergence

I want to evaluate this alternating sum using few of standard summation  $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \tan(\frac{1}{n!})$ but i didn't succeed. This sum has alternating sign and it gives $0$ for some values of $n.$ Really the latter mixed me to know the exact sign of that sum however [wolfram alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=sum(+((-1)%5En)tan+(1%2Fn!)),+n%3D0+to+infty) assumed that converge for large $n$  to $\sim0.41\cdots$ , Now my question here is:

> > **Question:**
> >     What is the sign and exact value  of this sum: $\sum_{n=0}^{+\infty}(-1)^n \tan(\frac{1}{n!})$ ?

Comment: I don't know why you'd think this was possible. Regardless, what's the definition of $n!$ for $n<0$?

Comment: If you find the sum of the first $10$ or so terms and if you can then prove that the sum of the remaining terms is very small in absolute value, then that gives you the sign. When $x$ is close to $0$, as is $1/n!$ when $n$ is large, then the ratio of $\tan x$ to $x$ is close to $1. \qquad$

Comment: You can also exploit the fact that $\lim\limits_{x\rightarrow0}\frac{\tan{x}}{x}=1$, thus $\tan{\frac{1}{n!}}\sim \frac{1}{n!}$.

Comment: This can be resummed from n=2 -- the first two terms cancel. I think what results after changing order of summation might require acrobatics with the Kampé de Fériet function for a closed form.

Comment: @MichaelHardy The sign is positive for every Leibniz series with positive first term (and we can consider the series starting at $n=2$), because the sum of the first two terms is less than the sum.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in comments, the best you can do is just to compute terms.

$$S_p=\sum_{n=0}^{p}(-1)^n \tan(\frac{1}{n!})$$ will give the following table
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 0 & 1.55740772465490223051 \\
 1 & 0.00000000000000000000 \\
 2 & 0.54630248984379051326 \\
 3 & 0.37807527154154805200 \\
 4 & 0.41976606761920965972 \\
 5 & 0.41143254137928324024 \\
 6 & 0.41282143116123408937 \\
 7 & 0.41262301846021771374 \\
 8 & 0.41264782004752438635 \\
 9 & 0.41264506431560198078 \\
 10 & 0.41264533988879422065 \\
 11 & 0.41264531483668583521 \\
 12 & 0.41264531692436153399 \\
 13 & 0.41264531676377109562 \\
 14 & 0.41264531677524184122 \\
 15 & 0.41264531677447712485 \\
 16 & 0.41264531677452491962 \\
 17 & 0.41264531677452210817 \\
 18 & 0.41264531677452226436 \\
 19 & 0.41264531677452225614 \\
 20 & 0.41264531677452225655 \\
 21 & 0.41264531677452225653
\end{array}
\right)$$ which not recognized by inverse symbolic calculators.

What would be interesting to know is : how many $p$ terms are to be added to get $k$ exact significant figures ? Since it is an alternating series, we need to solve
$$\tan(\frac{1}{(p+1)!}) < 10^{-k}$$ and since $\tan(\epsilon)\approx \epsilon$, this reduces to $(p+1)! >10^k$.

If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k), using $a=1$, @robjohn's fantastic approximation would write
$${p\sim  e\exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(\frac{2k\log(10)-\log(2\pi)}{2e} \right)\right)-\frac32}$$ and then the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
 k & \lceil p\rceil \\
 10 & 13 \\
 20 & 21 \\
 30 & 28 \\
 40 & 34 \\
 50 & 41 \\
 60 & 47 \\
 70 & 53 \\
 80 & 58 \\
 90 & 64 \\
 100 & 69 \\
 200 & 120 \\
 300 & 166 \\
 400 & 210 \\
 500 & 253 \\
 600 & 294 \\
 700 & 334 \\
 800 & 373 \\
 900 & 411 \\
 1000 & 449
\end{array}
\right)$$