# How to solve inequalities of the form $\frac{a^n}{n!}<b$?

Tags: inequality, problem-solving

In Taylor's series, to determine the number of terms needed to obtain the desired accuracy, sometimes one needs to solve inequalities of the form $$\frac{a^n}{n!}<b,$$
where $a$ and $b$ are fixed positive numbers. In most textbooks in calculus, the only introduced method to solve $\frac{a^n}{n!}<b$ for $n$ is trial and error. While this method works well in many cases, I feel that it is inefficient when $a$ is large and $b$ is small. (For example, how about solving $\frac{1000^n}{n!}<0.01$?)

My Question: Apart from using brutal force, is there another method to solve the inequality $\frac{a^n}{n!}<b$ for $n$?

Answer (score 1):

I am quite certain that this inequality doesn't have an analytical solution. But usually in these problems, we deal with fairly large values of $n$ to the extent that [Stirling's approximation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling%27s_approximation) is reasonably accurate. So if you replace $n!$ with its approximation:
$$\frac{a^n}{n!}\approx\frac{(ae)^n}{n^n\sqrt{2\pi n}}<b$$
and then take logarithm of both sides
$$n(\ln a+1)-(n+\frac12)\ln n<b+\frac12\ln(2\pi)$$
the only nonlinear term in the above inequality is $\ln n$, but it looks much simpler to check this one rather than the original inequality. For example, if $a=1000$ and $b=0.01$ as you say, then
$$7.9n-(n+0.5)\ln n<0.01+0.919=0.929$$
and you can easily (well, sort of) find an approximation of $n$ by applying Newton's method to [solve this](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=solve%5B7.9x-(x%2B0.5)ln+x%3D%3D.929,x%5D) inequality:
$$n\approx 2693$$

Comment: Thank you! Your answer is crystal clear and I have learnt a lot from it. Many thanks again!

Answer (score 1):

Answering [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, @robjohn proposed an extremely nice approximation.

Applied to your problem, this would give
$$\color{blue}{n=-\frac{\log \left(2 \pi  a b^2\right)}{2 \,W\left(-\frac{\log \left(2 \pi  a
   b^2\right)}{2 e a}\right)}-\frac 12}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Using your values $(a=1000,b=0.01)$, in the real domain, this would give $n=2718.0142$ while the exact solution would be $2718.0096$.

Quite impressive, isn't it ?

**Edit**

For conveniency, let $k=-\frac{\log \left(2 \pi  a   b^2\right)}{2 e a}$ to make
$$n=ea \frac k {W(k)}-\frac 12$$ When, as in your case, $k$ is small, you can approximate the result using
$$n=ea \left(1+k-\frac{k^2}{2}+O\left(k^3\right)\right)-\frac12$$ which, for the working case, would give the same result.

Another (better) approximation could be
$$n=ea\frac{2+3 k}{2+k}-\frac 12$$

Comment: Yes, very impressive! I am surprised that you can find such an accurate approximation!

Comment: @Zuriel. I shall add a few things to my answer.

Comment: @Zuriel. Soory ! I had a typo (missing the $-\frac 12$). Still better !