# What is equivalent of $\Gamma(n/2)$?

Tags: gamma-function, spheres

I should solve $\pi^{n/2} / \Gamma(n/2 + 1) = 1$. Therefore, I need to know other forms of $\Gamma(n/2)$ or $(n/2)!$.
I have already checked the Mathematica and MathWorld, very well. But unfortunately, I had not any progress so far.

The best way that I have done is to find the most similar statistical distribution, which is a mixture of Levy distribution and uniform distribution.

Then I tried to fit the best curve to recognize the parameters. Then I changed the parameters with their rationalized one -I mean one integer divided by another integer-, and replaced them in mixture distribution and then I fully simplified the final expression completely.At the end, I verified it to measure the residuals and I repeated the above procedure again and again to find the better and better result.

However, it is a approximately solution, but I need a exact one.

Comment: Hello, welcome to MSE. Please use $ signs to format your mathematics.

Comment: Is $n$ an integer? If yes, you just have to consider when $n$ is even and when $n$ is odd

Comment: No. It could be belongs to Integer or Real numbers and omit the complex numbers. Actually, I know the exact solution, which is 12.76405293503267913265321996..., but I don't know how to reach that.

Comment: "$12.76405293503267913265321996...$" is not an exact solution. It is a close approximation, but until you specify what *all* "..." stands for, it is not exact.

Answer (score 0):

You could get a nice *approximation* of the solution.

Let $m=\frac n2$ which means that you want to solve the equation
$$m! =\pi ^m$$

If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a magnificent approximation by @robjohn.

Applied to you case $(a=\pi,k=0)$
$$m=-\frac{\log (2 \pi^2 )}{2 W\left(-\frac{\log (2 \pi^2  )}{2 e \pi}\right)}-\frac{1}{2}$$ that is to say
$$n=-\frac{\log (2 \pi^2 )}{ W\left(-\frac{\log (2 \pi^2  )}{2 e \pi}\right)}-1$$ which is $\approx 12.748$ (relative error of $0.12$%).