# If $f(x) = xe^{-x^2}$, how many Taylor series terms are necessary to ensure our approximation of $f(1)$ is within $10^{-6}$?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, power-series, taylor-expansion

For $f(x) = xe^{-x^{2}}$ the taylor series is given by $$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n} x^{2n + 1}}{n!}.$$

How many terms are necessary to approximate $f(1)$ to $10^{-6}$ accuracy?

---

If we define the partial sum $s_{k, x  =1} = \sum_{n = 0}^{k} \frac{(-1)^{n} }{n!}$, I think I just need to find the minimum value of $k$ so that

$$|s_{k} -  e^{-1}| < 10^{-6}$$

Is there a way to find this without bruteforce?

Comment: Hint: write the remainder in lagrange form explicitly.

Answer (score 1):

You must take into account that this is an alternating series. So, considering
$$\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n} x^{2n + 1}}{n!}=\sum_{n=0}^{p}\frac{(-1)^{n} x^{2n + 1}}{n!}+\sum_{n=p+1}^{\infty}\frac{(-1)^{n} x^{2n + 1}}{n!}$$ you need to find (since $x=1$) the value of $p$ such that 
$$\frac 1{(p+1)!} < 10^{-k}\implies (p+1)! =10^k$$
If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a magnificent approximation by @robjohn for the inverse of the factorial function.

Using $a=1$, you should get
$$p+1=\frac{2 k \log (10)-\log (2 \pi )}{2 W\left(\frac{2 k \log (10)-\log (2 \pi )}{2
   e}\right)}-\frac 12 \implies \color{blue}{p=\frac{2 k \log (10)-\log (2 \pi )}{2 W\left(\frac{2 k \log (10)-\log (2 \pi )}{2
   e}\right)}-\frac 32}$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Since the argument is quite large, you can evaluate Lmabert function using 
$$W(t)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(6-9L_2+2L_2^2)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$ (as given in the linked Wikipedia page).

Fo $k=6$, this will give $p=8.44$; so take $p=9$. Just checking $9!=362880 < 10 ^6$ and $10!=3628800> 10^6$.

Comment: Hello, shouldn't we need $10$ terms since the expansion starts at $0$?