# Calculate an infinite series by computer: get sum and number of terms for given precision

Tags: infinite-product

I need to find a sum and number of terms in an infinite series if **ε** ∈ (0;1) and **x** ∈ (1;5):

$$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{k^2x^k}{(k+1)!}$$

I was able to convert it into a simpler form, but stuck there:

$$\lim_{k→∞} \frac{x^k×k^2}{k!×(k+1)} = e^x \frac{k^2}{k+1}$$

Can you suggest a direction to simplify the $\frac{k^2}{k+1}$ portion, please?

Comment: I'm not sure what you did above , but in the limit part that's wrong: it cannot be that the limit when $\;k\to\infty\;$ is something were $\;k\;$ appears... Also that...sign...like epsilon or something at the end of your first line: what is that in $\;(0,1)\;$ ?

Comment: What you need to do is determine how large is the $k$th term for the particular $x$. For example, pick the upper bound of your interval $x=5$. Let's say you measure precision in the number of correct decimal digits. Then you need to pick some $d$ and find $k$ such that $$\frac{k^2 5^k}{(k+1)!}< 10^{-d}$$ Then you can say that you need at least $k$ terms to get $d$ digits. Obviously, we should be using partial sums instead of a single term, but your series converges fast as factorials overtake the powers. So this bound should be a good start

Comment: And whatever you did with the limit is wrong as DonAntonio pointed out. What were you trying to do?

Comment: Thanks a lot for your input, @DonAntonio and Yuriy S! I would clarify the epsilon meaning with my professor because I was assuming that it's just my lack of knowledge about precisions in math (because I only know about $10^{-n}$ type of notations. • • •

I've naively tried a limit because the series is convergent, so I was thinking that sum and limit notations are the same. I get that this was wrong assumption.

Comment: Just got a confirmation: ε ∈ (0;1) in CS class tasks, in my University at least, means that user can specify any input from 0 to 1. So the resulting epsilon would be in an expected $10^{-d}$ format.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$$
\begin{align}
\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{k^2x^k}{(k+1)!}
&=\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{((k+1)k-(k+1)+1)\,x^k}{(k+1)!}\tag1\\
&=\sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}+\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}\tag2\\
&=x\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}+\frac1x\left(\sum_{k=0}^\infty\frac{x^k}{k!}-1\right)\tag3\\
&=(x-1)e^x+\frac{e^x-1}x\tag4\\[3pt]
&=\frac{(x^3+1)e^x-(x+1)}{x(x+1)}\tag5
\end{align}
$$
Explanation:
$(1)$: $k^2=(k+1)k-(k+1)+1$
$(2)$: cancel numerators and denominators
$\phantom{\text{(2):}}$ since $(k+1)k=0$ when $k=0$, we can remove the $k=0$ term from the first sum
$(3)$: substitute $k\mapsto k+1$ in the first sum and $k\mapsto k-1$ in the last sum
$(4)$: recognize the series for $e^x$
$(5)$: simplify the fraction

Comment: I had the big pleasure to show again your beautiful approximation. Cheers.

Comment: So interesting that your final answer is exactly that of mine, yet you are complaining me..........

Comment: Oh God, so results are the same? Is it possible to get rid of $x^3+1$?

Comment: @MostafaAyaz: your answer was not correct until you edited it. Now that you've added the $-\frac1x$, it matches my answer.

Comment: @terales: Both $(4)$ and $(5)$ are complete answers. $(4)$ is nice in that the limit as $x\to0$ can be seen more easily. $(5)$ is nice in that it is a bit cleaner. However, my answer is not the same as Mostafa Ayaz's answer before he corrected it.

Answer (score 2):

$$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{k^2x^k}{(k+1)!}{\\=\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{(k^2+k)x^k}{(k+1)!}-\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{kx^k}{(k+1)!}\\=\sum_{k=1}^∞ \frac{x^k}{(k-1)!}-\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{kx^k}{(k+1)!}\\=xe^x-\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{kx^k}{(k+1)!}}$$also $$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{kx^k}{(k+1)!}=\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{x^k}{k!}-\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{x^k}{(k+1)!}=e^x-\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{x^{k+1}}{x(k+1)!}=e^x-{1\over x}(e^x-1)$$therefore $$\sum_{k=0}^∞ \frac{k^2x^k}{(k+1)!}=e^x(x-1+{1\over x})-{1\over x}$$

Comment: Wow, thanks! It took me 30 mins to understand tricks with $k^2=k^2 + k-k$, $x^k=x×x^{k-1}$ and $kx^k=(k+1)x^k-x^k$. Now I see how beautiful your solution is!

Comment: I'm happy if it could help you!

Comment: Notice that the series converges to $0$ at $x=0$, but $e^x\!\left(x-1-\frac1x\right)$ blows up.

Answer (score 2):

*I had very serious mistakes in my answer. Trying to fix them now.*

After Yuriy S's comment, if you need to find $k$ such that
$$\frac{k^2\, x^k}{(k+1)!}< 10^{-d} \tag 1$$
Since $$\frac{k^2}{(k+1)!}=\frac k{k+1} \frac 1 {(k-1)!}\sim \frac 1 {(k-1)!}$$
we can approximate $(1)$ by equation
$$(k-1)!  = ( x\,{10^d})\,x^{k-1}$$ or, simpler,
$$n!= (x\,10^d)\, x^n \qquad \text{where }\qquad n=k-1$$ If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a magnificent approximation of the inverse factorial function which was proposed by @robjohn.

Applied to this case, this would give
 $$\color{blue} { k\sim e\, x\,e^{W(t)}+\frac 12} \qquad \text{where }\qquad \color{blue} {t=\frac {\log \left(\frac{x\, 10^{2 d}}{2 \pi }\right) } {2e x }}\tag 2$$ where appears $W(.)$ which is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Let us try for a few values of $x$ and $d$. The next table reports in the real domain the value given by the approximation $(2)$ as well as the exact solution of $(1)$. You just need to use the next integer.
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 x & d & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 4 & 8.33367 &  8.28080 \\
 1 & 5 & 9.41743 &  9.37320 \\
 1 & 6 & 10.4438 &  10.4056 \\
 1 & 7 & 11.4258 &  11.3922 \\
 1 & 8 & 12.3721 &  12.3420 \\
 1 & 9 & 13.2888 &  13.2615 \\
   &   &         &          \\
 2 & 4 & 12.0127 &  11.9689 \\
 2 & 5 & 13.2892 &  13.2517 \\
 2 & 6 & 14.5002 &  14.4674 \\
 2 & 7 & 15.6595 &  15.6302 \\
 2 & 8 & 16.7765 &  16.7500 \\
 2 & 9 & 17.8579 &  17.8338 \\
   &   &         &          \\
 3 & 4 & 15.3123 &  15.2744 \\
 3 & 5 & 16.7140 &  16.6810 \\
 3 & 6 & 18.0471 &  18.0178 \\
 3 & 7 & 19.3250 &  19.2987 \\
 3 & 8 & 20.5572 &  20.5333 \\
 3 & 9 & 21.7508 &  21.7288 \\
   &   &         &          \\
 4 & 4 & 18.4409 &  18.4071 \\
 4 & 5 & 19.9348 &  19.9051 \\
 4 & 6 & 21.3592 &  21.3326 \\
 4 & 7 & 22.7268 &  22.7028 \\
 4 & 8 & 24.0470 &  24.0250 \\
 4 & 9 & 25.3267 &  25.3063 \\
   &   &         &          \\
 5 & 4 & 21.4717 &  21.4412 \\
 5 & 5 & 23.0379 &  23.0108 \\
 5 & 6 & 24.5347 &  24.5104 \\
 5 & 7 & 25.9744 &  25.9521 \\
 5 & 8 & 27.3656 &  27.3452 \\
 5 & 9 & 28.7152 &  28.6963 
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Thanks for an answer! I can't get "assume that k is large and reduce the problem to…" part. $k$ seems to be less than 1000 for a precision of 4 digits, isn't it?

Comment: @terales. In fact, it is a typo ! $k$ does not need to be large at all. I shall edit now. Cheers.

Comment: @terales. $\frac{k^2}{(k+1)!}=\frac k {k+1} \times \frac{1}{(k-1)!}\approx \frac{1}{(k-1)!}$

Comment: Wow, how elegant it is! Thanks a lot for your comment from the real math side!