# For What Non-Negative Integer Values of $n$ is $n!\geq 3^n$

Tags: proof-writing, numerical-methods, factorial

How could I solve for the $n$ in this instance using discrete methods or is this something that I have to do by hand/computer? I've seen this problem in inductive proofs but the base case is usually given or calculated manually, is there a way to calculate using other methods?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Making the problem more general, at a point, you will need to solve for $n$ the equation
$$n!=a^n$$
If you have a look at [this question of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k), you will find a magnificent approximation proposed by @robjohn, an eminent MSE user. Making $k=0$, his approximation write
$$\color{blue}{n\sim ea\exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(-\frac{ \log(2\pi a)}{2ea}\right)\right)-\frac12}$$
 where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

For illustration, a few results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 0.92884 & 1.00000 \\
 2 & 3.44447 & 3.45987 \\
 3 & 6.00778 & 6.01602 \\
 4 & 8.60960 & 8.61515 \\
 5 & 11.2347 & 11.2389 \\
 6 & 13.8753 & 13.8787 \\
 7 & 16.5270 & 16.5297 \\
 8 & 19.1868 & 19.1892 \\
 9 & 21.8531 & 21.8552 \\
 10 & 24.5245 & 24.5264 \\
 11 & 27.2001 & 27.2018 \\
 12 & 29.8792 & 29.8807 \\
 13 & 32.5613 & 32.5627 \\
 14 & 35.2459 & 35.2471 \\
 15 & 37.9327 & 37.9339 \\
 16 & 40.6214 & 40.6225 \\
 17 & 43.3119 & 43.3129 \\
 18 & 46.0038 & 46.0048 \\
 19 & 48.6971 & 48.6980 \\
 20 & 51.3917 & 51.3925
\end{array}
\right)$$

In the linked Wikipedia page, you will find series expansions for an approximation of $W(x)$ that you could use with a pocket calculator.

Comment: This is great, thanks for the answer and links!

Comment: @Dmitriy. It is more than great ! It is a splendid approximation that I now use very often. And you are very welcome. Cheers.

Answer (score 2):

$$2!<3^2$$
$$3!<3^3$$
$$4!<3^4$$
$$5!<3^5$$
$$6!<3^6$$
$$7!\geq 3^7$$
Afterwards, $\forall n\geq 8$,
$$n!=(n)(n-1)...(9)(8)7!$$
$$\geq (3)(3)...(3)(3)7!$$
$$=3^{n-7}7!$$
$$\geq 3^{n-7}.3^7$$
$$=3^n$$

Hope it helps:)

Answer (score 1):

You can find when the geometric mean of the LHS is greater-than or equal to that of the RHS. Since the RHS is constant in this regard, you want to know for which n,

$$\sqrt[n]{1\cdot 2\cdots n} \ge 3$$

One way to get an upper bound amounts to finding $k$ such that $1\cdot 2\cdot k\cdot (k+1)\ge3^4$. That is, you need two consecutive integers which more than "balance out" the geometric discrepancy with 3 from 1 and 2.

$$2k^2+2k-81 \ge 0$$

Which should be straight-forward. In this case the upper bound ends up being the correct $k$, but in general you may have a set of values to check.