# Are there non-integer solutions to $x!=12!y!$ that make use of the Gamma function?

Tags: gamma-function

I came across a math question today which asked for the solutions to $$x!=12!y!$$ 
I was wondering if there were any non-integer solutions to the equation using the extended definition of the factorial as $\Gamma(n) = (n-1)!$

Comment: An evident solution (a trivial one) is $(x,y)=(12,1)$ (also with $y=0$). It is not hard, I think, to prove there are not non-trivial solutions.

Comment: If I was to try, I would convert the problem to binomial (m,n) form and try from there.  The binomial coefficients are forced to be an integer.  There is also the pochhammer function (a)_n which has integer results and a _lot_ of proven 
properties.

Comment: HINT.- $11|x!\Rightarrow x\ge12\Rightarrow 13\cdot14\cdot15\cdots x=y!$

Answer (score 1):

There are a non-trivial solution besides the trivial ones $(x,y)=(12,1),(12,0)$ and this solution is unique. 
From $x!=12!y!$ we have $x\gt y$ so putting $x=y+h$ we get
$$y!(y+1)(y+2)\cdots(y+h)=12!y!\iff (y+1)(y+2)\cdots(y+h)=12!$$ Clearly the $LHS$ has no more than eleven factors (really less!).

When $y+1=12!=2^{10}\cdot3^5\cdot5^2\cdot7\cdot11$ the first degree equation give us always a solution.We have $$\color{red}{(x,y)=(12!,12!-1)}$$

NOTE.- Always, for all $n$ one has $(n!)!=n!(n!-1)!$ wich is easy to prove.

Proving now with the successive equations of degree two, three, etc, Wolfram calculator gives non-integer (real) solutions.Thus the given non-trivial solution is unique.

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine asking for the solution of $$n!=a^n 10^k$$ you will see a magnificent approximation built by @robjohn for this last equation.
$$
n\sim ea\exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(\frac k{ea}\log(10)-\frac1{2ea}\log(2\pi a)\right)\right)-\frac12$$ where appears Lambert function.

For your cas, let $n=x$, $a=1$, $10^k=12!\, y!=12!\,\Gamma(y+1)$ to get

$$\color{blue}{x=e \exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(\frac 1 e\log \left(\frac{12! \,\Gamma (y+1)}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\right)\right)\right)-\frac12}$$ which will work for any value of $y$.

Trying for a few integer values of $y$, here are some results for $x$
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 y & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 0 & 11.9987 & 12.0000 \\
 1 & 11.9987 & 12.0000 \\
 2 & 12.2720 & 12.2732 \\
 3 & 12.7005 & 12.7017 \\
 4 & 13.2336 & 13.2348 \\
 5 & 13.8429 & 13.8439 \\
 6 & 14.5099 & 14.5109 \\
 7 & 15.2221 & 15.2231 \\
 8 & 15.9705 & 15.9714 \\
 9 & 16.7484 & 16.7492 \\
 10 & 17.5505 & 17.5513 \\
 20 & 26.3227 & 26.3232 \\
 30 & 35.7007 & 35.7010 \\
 40 & 45.3096 & 45.3098 \\
 50 & 55.0341 & 55.0342 \\
 60 & 64.8259 & 64.8261 \\
 70 & 74.6611 & 74.6612 \\
 80 & 84.5261 & 84.5262 \\
 90 & 94.4127 & 94.4128 \\
 100 & 104.316 & 104.316 \\
 200 & 203.764 & 203.764 \\
 300 & 303.500 & 303.500 \\
 400 & 403.333 & 403.333 \\
 500 & 503.214 & 503.214 \\
 600 & 603.123 & 603.123 \\
 700 & 703.050 & 703.050 \\
 800 & 802.989 & 802.989 \\
 900 & 902.937 & 902.937 \\
 1000 & 1002.89 & 1002.89
\end{array}
\right)$$