# Approximating cos(43) with error less than $8/60000$

Tags: calculus

I have this problem I know I need to approximate the value with taylor polynomial and its error formula is
$$|R_n(x)|\leq \frac{1}{(n+1)!}|x-a|^{n+1}$$
but i couldnt figured it out i should calculate up to which degree. Should I use radians? Can anyone help me about that

Comment: Is $43$ degrees or radians?  I would guess degrees, but radians is standard.  If degrees, you know the value and all the derivatives at $a=45^\circ$, so that is a good place to start.  To find the degree, you need to make the right hand side smaller than the requirement.  Note that $x-a$ should be expressed in radians, so will be rather small.  It won't take a very high degree.

Comment: so i need to take $a=\pi/4$ am i right

Comment: but how can i bound the error? it is not a good bound i think

Comment: I wish but i still have trouble with this

Comment: You know what $x-a$ is.  Just compute the right hand side for various $n$ until it falls below $8/60000$.  I find even without the $(n+1)!$ factor $n=2$ is good enough.  There should be a factor of one of the derivatives of $f$, but they are bounded by $1$ here so you can ignore it.

Comment: I'm sorry but I am confused, how can $n=2$ give me something like $8/60000$

Comment: $x-a=\frac \pi{90} \approx \frac 1{30}$, so $(x-a)^3 \approx \frac 1{27000}\lt \frac 8{60000}$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Too complex for sure but interesting problem.*

Making the problem more general, since by Taylor we have
$$\cos \left(\frac{\pi }{4}-x\right)=\sum_{n=0}^p (-1)^n \frac{\cos \left(n\frac{\pi  }{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)}{n!} x^n+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty (-1)^n \frac{\cos \left(n\frac{\pi  }{2}+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)}{n!} x^n$$
$$|R_p|=\frac 1 {\sqrt 2} \frac{x^{p+1}}{(p+1)!}$$ and you want to know $p$ such that $|R_p|\leq \epsilon$.

This write
$$(p+1) ! > \frac {x^{p+1}} {\epsilon\sqrt 2}$$ If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a magnificent approximation provided by @robjohn. Adapted to your problem, this will give
$$p=e x \exp\Big[W\left(-\frac{\log \left(4 \pi  x \epsilon ^2\right)}{2 e x}\right) \Big] -\frac 32$$ where appears [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). For sure, you will need to take $\lceil p\rceil$.

Appled to your case, this would give $p=1.267$ then $p=2$. Checking for $x=\frac \pi {90}$
$$|R_2|=\frac{\pi ^3}{64 \sqrt{2}}\approx \frac{\pi ^3}{4374000 \sqrt{2}}\approx 5.0 \times 10^{-6} < \frac 8 {60000}$$ while
$$|R_1|=\frac{\pi ^2}{16200 \sqrt{2}}\approx  4.3 \times 10^{-4} > \frac 8 {60000}$$

Just to show the quality of the approximation, the exact solution for your numbers would be $p=1.271$.

Doing the same for a value of $\epsilon$ $1000$ times smaller, would give $p=2.282$ then $p=3$.