# Calculate cos 43(degree) with an error less than 1/20.000

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion

That's my homework. I've been looking for "Taylor series" and trying to understand it. Seen some solutions but i think they're not that explanatory. Can you help me?

Comment: This site is not a homework completion service.  Please show your own efforts.

Comment: $$\cos(43^\circ) = \cos(45^\circ-2^\circ) = \frac{\cos 2^\circ+\sin 2^\circ}{\sqrt{2}} = \frac{1-2\sin^2 1^\circ+\sin 2^\circ}{\sqrt{2}} $$ and the problem boils down to estimating $\sin 1^\circ$ and $\sin 2^\circ$, very close to $\frac{\pi}{180}$ and $\frac{\pi}{90}$.

Comment: We just had this with error less than 8/60000.  See [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3734715/approximating-cos43-with-error-less-than-8-60000)