# Can you find a single solution of this function?

Tags: calculus, summation, hypergeometric-function

While playing around with the fresnel integrals, I came across this tantalizing power series (it is actually a particular hypergeometric series) which looks really similar to cosine!  I am calling this function $C_{\frac{1}{2}}$

$$ C_{\frac{1}{2}}(x)  = \sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^nx^{2n}}{(2n+\frac{1}{2})!} $$

My question is this: can you find any point $(x, C_{\frac{1}{2}}(x))$ that satisfies this function?  The only thing that I can say for sure is that the function approaches $0$ as $x$ gets arbitrarily large. A particular solution however would be VERY VERY interesting.

Comment: By writing $(2n+\frac{1}{2})$ I mean $\Gamma(2n +\frac{3}{2})$.  Also the value at $x=0$ is not 1 it is more like 1.128

Answer (score 2):

Amazing function between $\cos(x)$ and $\frac{\sin (x)}{x}$ !
$$f(x)=\sum_{n = 0}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+\frac{1}{2})!}x^{2n}=\frac{2 }{\sqrt{\pi }}\,\,\, _1F_2\left(1;\frac{3}{4},\frac{5}{4};-\frac{x^2}{4}\right)$$

For large values of $x$, it seems to be
$$f(x)\sim\frac{\sin \left(x+\frac{\pi }{4}\right)}{\sqrt{x} }-\frac{1}{2 \sqrt{\pi } x^2}+\frac{15}{8 \sqrt{\pi }   x^4}+\cdots$$
For $x=10$, the exact value is $-0.311997$ while the above truncated expansion gives $-0.311984$.

But going deeper in the simplification of the hypergeometric function
$$\color{red}{f(x)=\sqrt {\frac 2 x}\left(C\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi }} \right) \cos (x)+S\left(\sqrt{\frac{2x}{\pi }}   \right) \sin (x)   \right)}$$

**Edit**

You must be very careful if you just sum the terms for a given value of $x$. For example, the partials sums
$$S_p=\sum_{n = 0}^{p} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+\frac{1}{2})!}10^{2n}$$ are given below to show the serious problems.

$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
p & S_p \\
 0 & +1.12838 \\
 1 & -28.9617 \\
 2 & +162.087 \\
 3 & -372.314 \\
 4 & +465.962 \\
 5 & -374.415 \\
 6 & +210.195 \\
 7 & -88.4566 \\
 8 & +28.3181 \\
 9 & -7.75129 \\
 10 & +1.27170 \\
 11 & -0.593517 \\
 12 & -0.269554 \\
 13 & -0.317495 \\
 14 & -0.311378 \\
 15 & -0.312058 \\
 16 & -0.311992 \\
 17 & -0.311997
\end{array}
\right)$$  So, now, how many terms to be added for a given accuracy ?

Writing
$$f(x)=\sum_{n = 0}^{p} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+\frac{1}{2})!}x^{2n}+\sum_{n = p+1}^{\infty} \frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+\frac{1}{2})!}x^{2n}$$ we need to find $p$ such that
$$\frac{x^{2 (p+1)}}{\left(2p+\frac{5}{2}\right)!} \leq 10^{-k}$$ that we can rewrite as
$$\left(2p+\frac{5}{2}\right)! \geq x^{2p+\frac{5}{2}} \frac {10^k}{\sqrt x} $$

Looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will notice a superb approximation proposed by @robjohn. Applied to this case, it will give

$$\color{blue}{p \sim \frac 12 \left(x\, e^{1+W(t)}-3 \right)}\qquad \text{where}\qquad \color{blue}{t=\frac{1}{2 e x}\log \left(\frac{10^{2 k}}{2 \pi  x^2}\right)}$$
Using $k=6$ and $x=10$, this gives $p=16.6868$ so $p=17$ (just as in the above table).

Notice that the exact solution would be $p=16.6872$.

Comment: What are $C$ and $S$?

Comment: @LL3.14. Fresnel cosine and sine integrals.

Comment: I am glad to see that you noticed how it is between $cos(x)$ and $\frac{sin(x)}{x}$  :) .  Now do you mean EXACT when you say exact or do you mean approximating?  Also, I would love to see a derivation of the last statement, thanks!

Comment: @guavas222. It is exact.