# Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^2)$ with an error $\le 10^{-3}$

Tags: calculus, integration

Calculate $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^2)$ with an error $\le 10^{-3}$

Let $f(x)= \sin(x^2) $ continuous in [0,1] so by the MVT for integrals we know $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^2) = \sin(c^2) \; \text{for} \; c \in [0,1]$. I don't really know if this is of any help. Another thing that I know is that $\int_{0}^{1} \sin(x^2) \le \int_{0}^{1} x^2  \; \text{for} \; x \in [0,1]$. Any hints on how to resolve this ? Thanks in advance.

Comment: Use the Taylor series.

Comment: Error estimation of an alternating series is really cool...

Comment: The observation about the MVT is not of any help. You should replace $\sin(x^2)$ with its Maclaurin series. Then bring the integration into the summation. Then you will have an infinite series (no longer a power series). And you can approximate its value by taking a partial sum. How many terms you include affects how good the approximation is, and you can use standard features of an alternating series to know how many terms to include.

Comment: @alex.jordan I'll try that. Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use the Maclaurin series for $\;\sin x^2\;$, which converges absolutely at every point and thus you can integrate/differentiate it termwise:

$$\sin x^2=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n (x^2)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}\implies$$

$$\int_0^1\left(\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n x^{4n+2}}{(2n+1)!}\right)dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^1 x^{4n+2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\cdot\frac1{4n+3}$$

The above is a Leibniz  series and we can estimate its value in a reasonably easy way:Leibniz theorem telss us that if $\;S\;$ is the series sum and $\;S_n\;$ the $\;n\,$- th term of its partial sums sequence,  and $\;a_n\;$ is its general term sequence, then

$$|S-S_n|<|a_{n+1}|=\frac1{(2n+3)!(4n+7)}\stackrel{\text{we want!}}<\frac1{1000}$$

Well, you can now even try a very few times and get the correct value of $\;n\;$

Comment: Hi Don Antonio my friend!  I hope that you are staying safe and healthy.

Comment: @MarkViola Hi there, my good friend. We're doing fine so far, though my brother, wife and mother in law got the virus...But they're fine now. What's with you, anyway?

Comment: I'm sorry to hear about your family members, but pleased that they are OK!  My wife and I are doing well and following the guidelines of the CDC The WHO--"We won't get fooled again."

Comment: Good to know you'redoing fine. It's been a tough time, plans to travel and visit family went down the tubes....but hey! We've Zoom, at least.

Comment: Indeed.  Imagine if this pandemic occurred 30 years ago.

Comment: That'd be way worse! I'm a lecturer in an ingeneering college here and I would ve out of work without Zoom...But at least in that we were lucky. Thanks for asking and take care!

Comment: You're welcome.  And you also.

Answer (score 2):

Using the Taylor series representation of the sine function we have

$$\begin{align}
\int_0^1 \sin(x^2)\,dx&=\lim_{N\to\infty}\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(4n-1)(2n-1)!}\\\\&=\sum_{n=1}^N \frac{(-1)^{n-1}}{(4n-1)(2n-1)!}+E_N
\end{align}$$

Inasmuch as this is an alternative series, we would like to choose $N$ such that $E_N<0.001$ or

$$(4N+3)(2N+1)!>1,000$$

For $N=2$, we have $(4N+3)(2N+1)!=1,320$

Hence, we find that

$$\left|\int_0^1 \sin(x^2)\,dx-\left(\frac13-\frac1{42}\right)\right|=\left|\int_0^1 \sin(x^2)\,dx-\left(\frac{13}{42}\right)\right|<0.001$$

Comment: @karl Please let me know how I can improve my answer.  I really want to give you the best answer I can.

Comment: I find it useful. Thanks. The only problem I'm finding(not with your answer but overall) is that using wolfram alpha the integral converges to a very different approximation. Thanks

Comment: [HERE](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=Integral+sin%28x%5E2%29+dx+from+0+to+1) is output from Wolfram Alpha.  It agrees with the estimate within the 0.001 error.  It gives a result equal to roughly 0.310268.

Comment: You are right. I was calculating $\sum_{n=1}^2 (-1)^{n-1} a_{n+1}$ and not $\sum_{n=1}^2 (-1)^{n-1} a_{n}$ like i should, that was the problem. Thanks for taking the time to help me.

Comment: And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit.

Comment: Hi Mark ! If you enjoy approximations and have time to waste, have a look at my answer. Cheers and take care.

Comment: @karl And feel free to up vote an answer as you see fit.

Answer (score 0):

In the same spirit as the other answers but making the problem more general, consider
$$I=\int_0^t \sin(x^2)\,dx=
\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\int_0^t x^{4n+2}dx=\sum_{n=0}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\,\frac{t^{4n+3}}{4n+3}$$ Writing
$$I=\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\,\frac{t^{4n+3}}{4n+3}+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2n+1)!}\,\frac{t^{4n+3}}{4n+3}$$ you then want to know the value of $p$ such that
$$\frac {t^{4p+7}}{(2p+3)!\,(4p+7)} \leq 10^{-k}$$ that is to say
$$(2p+3)!\,(4p+7) \geq t^{4p+7}\,10^{k}\tag 1$$ To simplify the problem we shall approximate the lhs $\big[(4p+7\sim 4p+8=2(2p+4)\big]$and rewrite $(1)$ as
$$ (2p+4)! \geq \left(t^2\right)^{2 p+4}\frac{10^k} {2t}\tag 2$$
If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a magnificent approximation by @robjohn. Applied to your problem, this will give
$$\color{blue}{p \sim \frac 12  t^2\, e^{1+W(u)}-\frac 94} \qquad \text{where} \qquad \color{blue}{u=\frac 1{e\,t^2}\,\log \left(\frac{10^k}{2 t^2\sqrt{2 \pi } }\right)}\tag3$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. For sure, after computing $p$ as a real, you will need to take $\lceil p\rceil$.

Applied to your case $t=1$ and $k=3$, this gives $p=0.90006$ then $p=1$.

Satrting from @DonAntonio's last equation (copy/paste)

$$|S-S_n|<|a_{n+1}|=\frac1{(2n+3)!(4n+7)}\stackrel{\text{we want!}}<\frac1{1000}$$ the exact solution would be $n=0.92604$. Checking with $n=1$
$$\frac1{5!11}=\frac 1{1320}$$

But now, suppose that you want a very high accuracy such as $k=20$ : using $(3)$, you would find $p=8.49617$ then $p=9$. The exact result for @DonAntonio's last equation would be $8.50041$.

Comment: Hi Claude.  (+1) As always, very well done!   I hope you're doing well my friend!