# Is there a general way to find large enough $n \in \mathbb N$ such that for $k \in \mathbb N$: $n!>k^{n}$

Tags: real-analysis, combinatorics, inequality, factorial

I have found $n \in \mathbb N$ large enough such that $n!>2^{n}$ and $n!>5^{n}$ by simply "plugging in values". These facts have led me to consider a more general solution of $n!>k^{n}$ where $k \in \mathbb N$. In my attempts I have considered a function $f_{k}(n):=n!-k^{n}$ but it is discrete which makes working with derivatives painful. Is there a general solution and if so, how do I solve it?

I also thought of the following:

$n! > k^{n}\iff \log(n!)>n\log(k)\iff \frac{\log(n!)}{n}>\log(k)$

Comment: Use that $n! \ge (n/3)^n$

Answer (score 4):

Since $n! > (n/e)^n$,
if $n/e > k$ then
$n!> k^n$.

Therefore
$n > ek$ will work.

Answer (score 1):

Consider the equation
$$n! = k^n$$

If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a magnificent approximation which was proposed by @robjohn. Adapted to your problem, it gives

$$\color{blue}{n\sim e\,k\,\exp\left(W\left(-\frac{\log (2 \pi  k)}{2 e k}\right)\right)-\frac 12}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function. For sure, you will need to use $\lceil n \rceil$.

For illustration purposes, let us try for $k=2^p$ and admire the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & \text{approximation} & \text{exact} \\
 1 & 3.44447349465 & 3.45986564404 \\
 2 & 8.60959968277 & 8.61514776083 \\
 3 & 19.1868478144 & 19.1891973308 \\
 4 & 40.6214371321 & 40.6225104871 \\
 5 & 83.7910580611 & 83.7915684276 \\
 6 & 170.445206724 & 170.445454817 \\
 7 & 344.078832367 & 344.078954473 \\
 8 & 691.678759482 & 691.678820001 \\
 9 & 1387.21631441 & 1387.21634452 \\
 10 & 2778.63245721 & 2778.63247222 \\
 11 & 5561.80792391 & 5561.80793141 \\
 12 & 11128.5033891 & 11128.5033929 \\
 13 & 22262.2396826 & 22262.2396845 \\
 14 & 44530.0581347 & 44530.0581356 \\
 15 & 89066.0412025 & 89066.0412025
\end{array}
\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

let's consider $$\sum_{n\in\mathbb{N}}\frac{k^n}{n!}$$
for some $k\in\mathbb{R}$ the sum is convergent [Ratio test](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ratio_test). Therefore $$\frac{k^n}{n!}\:\xrightarrow[]{n\to\infty}\:0$$
Thus, from the definition of the limit assuming $M=1$, there exists such $N$ for which when $n>N$ takes place $\frac{k^n}{n!}<1$ so $k^n<n!$

(edit after the commentary): Using Stirling's approximation we can write:

$$n!= \sqrt{2 \pi n} \left(  \frac{n}{e} \right)^ne^{ \alpha_n}  \ge \left(  \frac{n}{e} \right)^n$$
the right side is greater than $k^n$ when $n/e>k$ so $n>ek$. This is a good estimate of practically the smallest $N_k=ek$ for which the above is the case.

Comment: I was looking for a way to determine the $N$ in terms of $k$.

Comment: Oh I understand. Sorry, I thought you were just proving the existence of such an $N$