# Relationship between size of $x$ and rate of convergence of Taylor series of $\sin{x}$.

Tags: convergence-divergence, power-series, taylor-expansion

I wrote a program to investigate how quickly $\sin{x}$ converges by seeing how long it took for an $x$ to differ from a partial sum by a certain amount. Here's a graph for the $n$th partial term with $n$ on the $x$-axis and the first $x$ to significantly differ (by more than 0.01) on the $y$-axis.

[image: graph]

It looks very linear which I found surprising and interesting. I'd appreciate if someone had a proof or heuristic as to why this is the case.

Answer (score 1):

Consider that
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)!} x^{2 n+1}+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty\frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n+1)!} x^{2 n+1}$$ and, since it is an alternating series, you want to know what is $p$ such that
$$\frac{x^{2p+3}}{(2p+3)!} \leq \epsilon \implies (2p+3)! \geq \frac{x^{2p+3} } \epsilon$$ This is almost exactly what I asked in [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k). Adapted to your problem and this formulation, this should give
$$2p+3 \sim  e x \exp\Big[W(t)  \Big]-\frac 12 \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=-\frac{\log \left(2 \pi  x \epsilon ^2\right)}{2 e x}$$ $W(t)$ being [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). So
$$p\sim  \frac{e}{2} x e^{W(t)}-\frac{7}{4}$$ and, for sure, you will use $\lceil p\rceil$.

Now, the problem is that $t$ will be very large (for example $x=\frac \pi 2$ and $\epsilon=10^{-20}$ would give $t=10.5172$). But we can use the expansion given in the Wikipedia page
$$W(t)=L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{(L_2-2) L_2}{2 L_1^2}+\frac{(2 L_2^2-9L_2+6) L_2}{6 L_1^3}+ ...$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

But, if $t$ is small, the result is "quite close" to linearity (as you observed).

Answer (score 0):

This is what happens near zero since $\lim\limits _{x\to0}\frac{sin x}{x}$=1 . But when x is large, this is not true since the limit will be zero as x goes to infinity.

Comment: Your answer doesn't seem to mention the higher order terms of the Maclaurin series, which seem relevant to the discussion. Without further context, it reads as if you might have misunderstood the question as asking why sine looks linear near the origin.