# Finding an order of $n$ such that a product is exponentially small in $n$

Tags: real-analysis, calculus

I am looking for a function $f$ s.t. if $t=O(f(n))$, where $O$ stands for Big-O notation, then:

$$\frac{t}{n}\times\frac{t-1}{n}\times\cdots \times \frac{2}{n}\sim e^{-an} \tag{1}$$

i.e. when the LHS of $(1)$ is exponentially small in $n$?

Say $t=n/2$, so $t=O(n)$, then the LHS of $(1)\leq \left(\frac{1}{2}\right)^n$ so it is exponentially small in $n$. But I was wondering if I can do better than that like what if $t=O(\sqrt{n})$ or something like that in which case I don't know if the LHS of $(1)$ would still be exponentially small?

Comment: Can you explain what you mean by the "$=$" sign in expression $(1)$? Do you mean equivalence?

Comment: @Bcpicao Yes, equivalence.

Comment: **HINT**: take the $\log$ and try to think about comparing the continuous equivalent of these sequences.

Comment: @Bcpicao Sorry didn't understand what you mean by continuous equivalent of these sequences. May I know which sequences?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You want
$$\frac{f(n)!}{n^{f(n)-1}}\sim e^{-an}.$$
Since
$$f(n)!\sim \sqrt{2\pi f(n)}\left(\frac{f(n)}e\right)^{f(n)},$$
so we want
$$n\sqrt{2\pi f(n)}\left(\frac{f(n)}{en}\right)^{f(n)}\sim e^{-an}.$$
Taking logs and writing $f(n)=f$ for simplicity, we have that
$$\log n+\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}2+\frac{\log f}2+f\cdot(\log f-\log n-1)+an$$
is asymptotically constant.
Writing $g=f/n$ (since $f$ should be a bit smaller than $n$),
$$\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}}2+\frac{\log g+3\log n}2+gn(\log g-1)+an\to c$$
for some constant $c$. The asymptotically largest terms here are $gn\log g$ and $an$, so we want
$$-g\log g\sim a,$$
so $g$ should be (around) a constant. So, $f$ should be asymptotically some constant times $n$.

Comment: I was gonna use functional analysis and integrals but indeed Stirling already did the job for us :) Nice one (+1)

Comment: @manifolded Isn't the LHS exactly $\frac{f(n)!}{n^{f(n)-1}}$?

Answer (score 1):

Starting from @Carl Schildkraut'answer, you want to solve for $f(n)$ the equation

$$\frac{[f(n)]!}{n^{f(n)-1}}= e^{-an}$$ To simplify notations, let $f(n)=y$ and $k=\frac{1}{n}e^{-a n}$ to make
$$y!=k\, n^y\tag 1$$

Looking at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will find a superb approximation proposed by @robjohn who is a very eminent user in this forum.

Adapted to $(1)$, it will give
$$y=e\,n\, \exp\Big[W\left(\frac{1}{2 e n}\log \left(\frac{k^2}{2 \pi  n}\right)\right) \Big]-\frac 12$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Back to the original notations, this will give
$$f(n)=e\, n\,\exp\Big[W\left(-\frac{a}{e}-\frac{3 \log (n)+\log (2 \pi )}{2 e n}\right) \Big]-\frac 12$$