# Constructing a rootfinding function with factorial

Tags: roots, factorial, computational-mathematics

I'm working on a root-finding problem and dealing with a function with factorial. $\epsilon$ is a very small machine error, approximately $2 \times 10^{-16}$, which is a tolerance to prevent infinite iterations. And $x$ is a known value, which are $[0.1,1,10,100,1000]$. Therefore, there are five functions I need to find the root of $n$.
$$
    r = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n + 1)!} \approx \epsilon
$$
My idea is that

\begin{align}
    r &= \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \\
    \log r &= \log \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!} \\
    \log r &= (n+1)\log x - \log (n+1)!
\end{align}
$\log r$ should be a number around $-16$ and we can find the root. But the problem requires me not to use Stirling's approximation; moreover, I cannot use cumulative sum for $\log$ because $n$ can be a decimal number. Could someone provide some ideas how to continue this problem? Thank you very much. No need to worry about root finding algorithm. I just need to construct a doable function that I can deal with on Python.

Comment: Why do you need non-integer $n$? The problem description sounds like you only need integer $n$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're extending factorials to real values, you'll probably want to look into the [Gamma Function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gamma_function).

$\Gamma(n+1) = n!$ when $n$ is a natural number, but $\Gamma$ can be defined for all complex numbers except for the negative integers. In Python you can use the function `lgamma` from the `math` module in the standard library. `lgamma` computes the log of the absolute value of the Gamma function.

Something like this could work to compute the function you're interested in

```
import math

def log_r(n: float, x: float) -> float:
    return (n + 1) * math.log(x) - math.lgamma(n)
```

though whether or not the Gamma function is actually what you want may be use case dependent.

Edit: I neglected to mention. If you plan to use Newton's method, you'll also need to be able to calculate the derivative of `lgamma`. In Python you can use [scipy.special.digamma](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.digamma.html) from the 3rd party scipy package.

Answer (score 1):

You want to solve for $n$ the equation $$ r = \frac{x^{n+1}}{(n+1)!}\implies (n+1)!=\frac{x^{n+1}}{r} $$

If you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a magnificent approximation proposed by @robjohn.

Adapted to your problem, the solution is
$$n \sim x \, e^{1+W(t)}-\frac 3 2 \qquad \text{with} \qquad t=-\frac{\log \left(2 \pi  r^2 x\right)}{2 e x}$$ $W(t)$ being Lambert function.

Let us try for $x=\pi$ and $r=10^{-20}$; this will give, as a real, $n=31.4795$ while the exact solution obtained using Newton method is $n=31.4800$.

If you cannot afford Lambert function, use the approximation
$$W(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$.

For the worked example, this would give $W(t)=1.35303$ while its exact value is $1.35116$.

**Edit**

Misreading, as @AlbertSteppi commented, I used Lambert function (what you did not want).

The only other way is a root-finding procedure and, for easiness, let us apply Newton method to find the zero of function
$$f(n)=\log (\Gamma (n+2))-(n+1)\log(x)+\log(r)$$
$$f'(n)=\psi (n+2)-\log (x)$$ So, the iterates will by
$$n_{k+1}=n_k -\frac{\log (\Gamma (n_k+2))-(n_k+1)\log(x)+\log(r)}{\psi (n_k+2)-\log (x) }$$ The problem is to find a "reasonable" value of $n_0$.

For the range $0 \leq n \leq 100$ a quick and dirty regression
$$\log (\Gamma (n+2)) \sim n ^a$$ gives $(R^2=0.9999782)$
$$\begin{array}{llll}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 1.28400 & 0.00011 & \{1.28378,1.28421\} \\
\end{array}$$

So, a starting point could be $$n_0=\big[-\log(r)\big]^{\frac 1a}$$

Trying with the previous problem, this would give the following iterates
$$\left(
\begin{array}{cc}
k & n_k \\
 0 & 19.741 \\
 1 & 32.930 \\
 2 & 31.493 \\
 3 & 31.480
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Note that this approximation depends on Stirling's approximation, which is disallowed by the problem statement.

Comment: @AlbertSteppi. You are right. I delete.