# If $n!>n^3$, find the value of $n$.

Tags: linear-algebra

I have a problem of getting $n$, I do not even know if it is possible.
If $\space n! > n^3 \space so \space n! = \left( \frac { n ( n + 1 ) } {2}\right ) ^ 2$

I tried different methodologies and still have nothing to stick with. I do not know which topic I should dig in to solve this problem.

Could you solve it with an explanation ?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. For some basic information about writing mathematics at this site see, *e.g*., [basic help on mathjax notation](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation), [mathjax tutorial and quick reference](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5020/mathjax-basic-tutorial-and-quick-reference), [main meta site math tutorial](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/68388/there-should-be-universal-latex-mathjax-guide-for-sites-supporting-it/70559#70559), and [equation editing how-to](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/1773/do-we-have-an-equation-editing-howto).

Comment: To be clear, are you trying to find an example of some specific $n$ which satisfies the inequality after you wrote "if", and also the equation you wrote after "so"? [if so, what you have now doesn't convey that very well]

Comment: i have to get n when !n > n^3 and n!=(n(n+1)2)2 @coffeemath

Comment: Hence your problem is to solve $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2> n^3$?

Comment: In your comment you wrote $!n$ but in question it is $n!.$ Which is it? because $!n$ has a different meaning...

Comment: i tried to proof that n! = (n(n+1)2)2 and it is not true in this case 
@MarcosEscartínFerrer

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer I think in addition OP wants the factorial of $n$ to be equal to the squared sum of first $n$ integers. [Don't know if that's powsible but I think OP is looking for that]

Comment: @MarcosEscartínFerrer That simplifies to $(n-1)^2>0$, i.e. $n\ne1$. It's a long way from solving the original problem.

Comment: I used wolfram alpha and $\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2> n^3$ gave me $n\neq 1$ while $n!=\left(\frac{n(n+1)}{2}\right)^2$ gave me $n=1$, so the solution is that there are no positive integer I guess.

Comment: i am also trying different methodologies and got the same conclusion @MarcosEscartínFerrer

Answer (score 0):

The simplest would be to try with your pocket calculator.

Let us make the problem more general and say that we want to solve for $n$ the equation
$$n!=a^n$$

If you have a look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a superb approximation given bt @robjohn. Adapted to the problem ($k=0$), we have
$$n \sim a\, e^{1+W(t)}-\frac 12\qquad \text{where} \qquad t=-\frac{\log (2 \pi  a)}{2 e a}$$ where $W(t)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function).

Working with real numbers, for $a=3$, this gives $n=6.00778$ while the exact solution given by Newton method is $n=6.01602$.

Since $t$ is small for $a>1$, you can use
$$W(t)=t-t^2+\frac{3 t^3}{2}-\frac{8 t^4}{3}+O\left(t^5\right)$$
$$e^{W(t)}=1+t-\frac{t^2}{2}+\frac{2 t^3}{3}-\frac{9 t^4}{8}+O\left(t^5\right)$$ or, even better
$$e^{W(t)}=\frac{101 t^2+174t+60}{17 t^2+114t+60}$$

Using the above, for $a=3$, you would obtain $n=6.00868$.