# In Maple, how do we compute $\sin{1}$ with an error of less than $10^{-17}$ using this very manual way?

Tags: calculus, taylor-expansion, maple

Suppose we would like to compute $\sin{1}$ with an error of less than $10^{-17}$ specifically using a Taylor polynomial at $\pi/2$ (instead of the easier route of doing the computation at $0$).

If we write

$$f(x)=\sin{x}=P_{n,a}(x)+R_{n,a}(x)$$

where $P_{n,a}(x)$ is the Taylor polynomial of degree $n$ for $f$ at $a$, and $R_{n,a}(x)$ is the remainder term, then by Taylor's Theorem we have

$$\sin{x}=\sum\limits_{i=0}^{2n+1} \left [\sin^{(i)}{(a)}\frac{(x-a)^{2n+1}}{(2n+1)!}\right ]+\frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}{(t)}}{(2n+2)!}(x-a)^{2n+2}, t\in (0,x)$$

$$R_{2n+1,a}(x)=\frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}{(t)}}{(2n+2)!}(x-a)^{2n+2}, t\in (0,x)$$

Then

$$R_{2n+1,\pi/2}(1)=\frac{\sin^{(2n+2)}{(t)}}{(2n+2)!}\left (1-\frac{\pi}{2}\right )^{2n+2}, t\in (0,1)$$

$$\leq \frac{1}{(2n+2)!}\left (1-\frac{\pi}{2}\right )^{2n+2}$$

$$<10^{-17}$$

$$\implies (2n+1)!>10^{17}\cdot \left (1-\frac{\pi}{2}\right )^{2n+1}\tag{1}$$

$$\implies (2n+1)!-10^{17}\cdot \left (1-\frac{\pi}{2}\right )^{2n+1}>0\tag{2}$$

Let's say we now want to use Maple to figure out which $n$ makes $(2)$ true. **Why doesn't the following work?**

```
f := n -> 10^(17)*[1 - 1/2*Pi]^(2*n + 2)

g := n -> (2*n + 2)!

h := n -> g(n) - f(n)    

is(h(1)>0)      // FAIL
```

Note that individually computing values of $f$, $g$, and $h$ works fine. In particular, `h(1)` produces a result. Why doesn't the function `is` work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your wrote,

```
10^(17)*[1 - 1/2*Pi]^(2*n + 2)
```

which is incorrect syntax for what you're trying to accomplish. In Maple group of terms is accomplished by using round-brackets, eg,

```
10^(17)*(1 - 1/2*Pi)^(2*n + 2)
```

Square-brackets form a *list*, not a scalar expression.

Maple allows you to concoct that weird kind of expression on the grounds that you *might* have some special use for it. But Maple doesn't necessarily see it and manipulate it like the scalar expression you presumably intended.

In other words, you've made a syntax mistake.

Answer (score 1):

*Just for your curiosity.*

There is an analytical solution to this problem.

Writing
$$\sin(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n)!}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n}=\sum_{n=0}^p \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n)!}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n}+\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(2 n)!}\left(x-\frac{\pi }{2}\right)^{2 n}$$ You are looking for $p$ such that

$$R_p=\frac 1 {(2p+2)!} \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-1\right)^{2 p+2} \leq 10^{-k}$$ that is to say
$$(2p+2)! \geq \left(\frac{\pi }{2}-1\right)^{2 p+2}\, 10^k$$

f you look at [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will see a superb approximation proposed by @robjohn. Adapted to your problem, it gives (as a real)

$$p \sim \frac{\pi -2}{4} \, e^{1+W(t)}-\frac 54 \qquad \text{where} \qquad  t=\frac{k \log (100)-\log ((\pi -2) \pi )}{e (\pi -2)}$$ $W(t)$ being Lambert function (present in Maple).

Trying for $k=100$, this gives as a real $p=29.853719$ while the exact solution is $p=29.853790$. So $\lceil p \rceil=30$.

Checking
$$R_{29}=2.94236\times 10^{-97} \qquad \text{while} \qquad R_{30}=2.53476\times 10^{-101}$$