# Avoiding Loss of Significance Due to Subtractive Cancellation

Tags: numerical-methods, computer-arithmetic

I am having trouble figuring out how to avoid subtractive cancellation without using Taylor series expansion for this problem:
$x − \sin x$

My initial thought is to use trig identities but I cannot figure out how to manipulate this properly.

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: What problems are you having with Taylor expansion specifically?

Comment: @emacsdrivesmenuts The questions has specifically restricted the use of Taylor Expansion

Answer (score 1):

Better than Taylor series would be the simplest Padé approximant
$$x-\sin(x)\sim\frac {10 \,x^3}{3(20+x^2)}$$ whose error is $\frac {11x^7}{50400}$.

More accurate would be
$$x-\sin(x)\sim\frac {28x^3(990-17x^2)}{15(11088+364x^2+5x^4 ) }$$  whose error is $\frac {11x^{11}}{457228800}$.

If you want to use Taylor series, there is a way to know exactly how many terms must be added for a given accuracy. If $n$ is the number of terms, you need to find $n$ such that
$$\frac{x^{2n+3}}{(2n+3)!} \leq 10^{-k}\quad \implies \quad (2n+3)! \geq x^{2n+3}\,10^k$$ and, using the approximation proposed by @robjohn [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k),

$$n\sim \frac {ex}2\exp\left(\operatorname{W}\left(\frac k{ex}\log(10)-\frac1{2ex}\log(2\pi x)\right)\right)-\frac74$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.