# Finding solution of an exponential function divided by factorial

Tags: exponential-function, factorial, queueing-theory

I need to find the solution of $\dfrac{4^n}{n!}=51.8682$. Though I need $n$ to be a natural number, if $n\in\mathbb{R}$, I can take the celling of $n$ for problem purpose.
It can be done by trial and error method. But one thing is noticeable that the denominator is increasing rapidly than the numerator. For $n=1,2,3$ the R.H.S is very far from the result. As $n$ increases, the fraction decreases and hence the fraction does not reach even at $50$.
Is there any way to solve this equation?

**Question added**
A cafeteria with self-service has an arrival rate of $12$/hour. The average time taken by a person to collect and eat his meal is $20$ minutes. Assuming that the inter-arrival times are exponentially distributed, how many seats must the cafeteria have to accommodate each customer with probability $0.95$?

**Solution:**
Here $\lambda=12$ persons/hour and $\mu=\dfrac{60}{20}=3$ customers/hour. Therefore $\rho=\dfrac {12}{3}=4$. We need to find $n$ so that $P_n=0.95$. Therefore we have
$
 \dfrac{\rho^ne^{-\rho}}{n!}=0.95\implies \dfrac{4^ne^{-4}}{n!}=0.95\implies \dfrac{4^n}{n!}=51.8682$

Comment: As you noticed, starting with $n=4$ it becomes a decreasing sequence. Thus, there is no solution.

Comment: @Vasili But there has to be a solution as the problem indicates.

Comment: The question concerns a cumulative probability.

Comment: @lulu would you like to explain it a bit more?

Comment: You are looking at the probability that exactly $n$ show up in some interval. You should be looking at the probability that *at most* $n$ people show up.

Comment: Note: the problem is a bit strange in that so few people come to the cafeteria. I wouldn't think you'd need very many seats to accommodate them.

Comment: @lulu Thanks for your suggestion. But I think in that case also, this problem would arise to find the value of $n$.

Comment: That is a trivial numerical problem.  Approximations are possible, but why bother?  The numbers are very small indeed so just do it exactly.

Comment: @lulu It is better not to use adjective "trivial". People who aren't at ease with maths receive the use of it as "you aren't intelligent enough to understand"

Comment: @JeanMarie  Thanks, fair point.  To be clear, I intended it to read as "this is a standard numerical problem, and it is probably optimal to solve it that way" but I appreciate that it could have been interpreted more harshly.

Comment: @lulu I'm not finding how cumulative density would resolve this issue. If it's possible for you to answer this question rather than commenting, it would be very nice!

Comment: I don't understand.  $X$, the number of people who arrive in a $20$ minute window, is a Poisson variable with mean $4$.  We want the least $n$ such that $P(X≤n)≥.95$ so just compute the cumulative Poisson distribution for $n=0, 1, 2, \cdots$ until you find one that works.  For large $n$, of course, $P(X≤n)$ approaches $1$ so we know there is a value that works and, indeed, it's quite small.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Working in the real domain, you can have an almost exact explicit solution.

Making the problem more general, you want to solve for $n$
$$\frac {a^n}{n!}=b \qquad \implies \qquad n!=\frac {a^n}{b}$$

If you look at [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k/2078194#2078194) of mine, you will see a superb approximation by @robjohn (one of our moderators).

Just make  $10^k=\frac 1b$ that is to say $k=-\frac {\log(b)}{\log(10)}$ to get
$$n \sim e a \exp\left(W\left( -\frac{\log \left(2 \pi  a b^2\right)}{2 e a} \right)\right)-\frac 12$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function)

The problem is that, with your numbers $(a=4,b=51.8682)$, the solution is **a complex number**.

Changing $b$ to its reciprocal would give $n=12.5120$ while its exact value is $12.5147$.