# Solution to $2^x=x!$

Tags: real-analysis, functions, factorial

I was trying to solve the equation for $x!=2^x$, where $x\ge0$.

I plotted it on Desmos and found two solutions for the same.

Attaching image for reference. [Graph plot of $2^x$ and $x!$](https://i.stack.imgur.com/vSRJ7.png)

As per the plot, there are two solutions for the equation. But I am only able to derive the solution $x=0$. (Through observation and guesswork).

How can the second solution be derived ($x\approx3.46$)?

I couldn't figure it out!

It looks so simple, yet its quite a bummer actually(at least for me).

Can someone please help regarding the same?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Though the second solution is not 3.46, but a real number between 3.459 and 3.460. A computer helped me determine that.

Comment: Giving far too many decimals, the second solution is $x = 3.45986564404499913418786108106898120\dots$ according to [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=x%21+%3D+2%5Ex).

Comment: I think we can not go out of an numerical method for this problem or re writing the problem as a integral representation $\Gamma(x+1)=2^{x}$, for $ x\geqslant 0$.

Comment: The second solution is quite close to $4e/\pi$. Coincidence?

Comment: @Dan probably coincidence, as it is accurate to only the second decimal digit.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I cannot see any form of analytical solution possible to this equation. Instead, you can set a function $$f(x)=2^x-\Gamma(x+1)$$ and perform numerical methods for the second solution. You can use Newton's method for approximating roots.

Here, we start with the initial value $x=3$

[image]
[image]

and so on to the desired accuracy.

The root we get is $$x\approx 3.45986564404499913418786108106898120277518459906428314529806887...$$

Comment: Then there is another question along the similar lines... $1/x!=1/2^(x-1). This one has a solution at x=2. Is there any way to compute it analytically, or it needs to be solved through numerical methods as helped out by you?

Comment: @lumberjack $1/x!=1/2^{x-1}$ is rewritten as $2^x=2\Gamma(x+1)$, which although cannot be solved analytically, has only two positive solutions that can be spotted via some intuitive insight. (ie 1 and 2)

Answer (score 4):

Looking at [this old question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k) of mine, you will find a superb approximation proposed by @robjohn (one of our moderators) for the solution of the general equation
$$\large x!=a^x$$

$$x\sim e a\exp\Bigg[W\left(-\frac{\log (2 \pi  a)}{2 e a}\right)\Bigg]-\frac 12$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

To show how good it is

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
a & \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 2 & 3.44447 &  3.45987 \\
 3 & 6.00778 &  6.01604 \\
 4 & 8.60960 &  8.61488 \\
 5 & 11.2347 &  11.2390 \\
 6 & 13.8753 &  13.8786 \\
 7 & 16.5270 &  16.5296 \\
 8 & 19.1868 &  19.1892 \\
 9 & 21.8531 &  21.8552 \\
 10 & 24.5245 &  24.5263 \\
 11 & 27.2001 &  27.2018 \\
 12 & 29.8792 &  29.8807 \\
 13 & 32.5613 &  32.5626 \\
 14 & 35.2459 &  35.2472 \\
 15 & 37.9327 &  37.9339 \\
 16 & 40.6214 &  40.6225 \\
 17 & 43.3119 &  43.3129 \\
 18 & 46.0038 &  46.0048 \\
 19 & 48.6971 &  48.6980 \\
 20 & 51.3917 &  51.3925 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: It is a nice answer!

Answer (score 1):

Let $f(x) =2^{x}-x!$.

We can see that $f(0)=0$ which implies $0$ is a root of $f(x)$.

Now we can see $f(3) > 0$ and $f(4) < 0$.

So by intermediate value theorem we can say that it has a root in between $3$ and $4$.

To find the approximated root we can use numerical approach. Better to use bisection method.