# Estimate $\int_{1/m}^{\infty} y^{-1} e^{-y} dy$

Tags: analysis

I want to estimate $$\int_{1/m}^{\infty} y^{-1} e^{-y} dy,$$where $m$ is a positive number.

**My Attempt**

$$\begin{aligned}
\int_{1/m}^{\infty} y^{-1} e^{-y} dy &= -y^{-1}e^{-y}|_{1/m}^{\infty} - \int_{1/m}^{\infty} y^{-2} e^{-y} dy\\
&\leq me^{-1/m}\leq m.
\end{aligned}$$

It seems that this estimate is not sharp enough. In fact, my intuition told me that the result may involve $\ln m$, but I cannot figure it out. Could you give me a hint? Any insight or help is appreciated.

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Here's [how to ask a good question](https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9959/how-to-ask-a-good-question). Follow these guidelines to get help in this forum. It's particularly important that you share your own work and thoughts on the problem to show that you have made a serious effort by yourself before asking for help, and you're not just trying to get others to solve it for you.

Comment: **Hint:** the integral from $1$ to infinity is just a constant. For the integral from $1/m$ to $1$, you can substitute $y=1/t$ and expand the exponential as a power series.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using the exponential integral function
$$\int y^{-1} e^{-y}\, dy=\text{Ei}(-y)$$ Then, using the incomplete gamma function equivalent
$$I=\int_{\frac 1m}^{\infty} y^{-1} e^{-y}\, dy=\Gamma \left(0,\frac{1}{m}\right)$$ and, if $m$ is large
$$I=\log (m)-\gamma +\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)\,(n+1)!\,m^{n+1}}$$

Not only it is alternating but moreover, it will converge very fast since
$$\left| \frac{a_{n+1}}{a_n}\right|=\frac{n+1}{m (n+2)^2}\sim \frac 1{mn}$$

This gives very simple bounds (as tight as you wish). The simplest would be
$$\log (m)-\gamma +\frac{1}{m}-\frac{1}{4m^2} <I < \log (m)-\gamma +\frac{1}{m}$$

Moreover, for calculation purposes, you can know in advance the number of terms to be added for a given accuracy. Writing the infinite sammation as
$$\sum_{n=0}^p\frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)\,(n+1)!\,m^{n+1}} +\sum_{n=p+1}^\infty \frac{(-1)^n}{(n+1)\,(n+1)!\,m^{n+1}}$$ you want to know $p$ such that
$$R_p=\frac 1 {(p+2) (p+2)! \,m^{p+2} }\leq 10^{-k}$$ or, to make it simpler,
$$ (p+3)! \,m^{p+2} \geq 10^k$$

If you look at [this old post of mine](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k), using @robjohn's approximation, we have, as a real,
$$p \sim \frac  1 m \,e^{1+W(t)} -\frac 7 2 \qquad \text{where} \qquad t=\frac m {2e}\log \left(\frac{10^{2 k}}{2 \pi  m}\right)$$

Answer (score 0):

Note that Ei(x)=\int_{-x}^{\infty}\frac{e^{-x}}{x}dx

the x value in this function is \frac{-1}{m}

Thus to find any value of this integral you can use the function

I=Ei(\frac{-1}{m}) , where Ei(x) is the exponential integral

Then you can use this infinite sum

Ei(x)=-\gamma-\ln(x)-\sum_{1}^{\infty}(\frac{(-x)^{k}}{kk!}) , where \gamma is the euler-mascheroni constant