# A way to solve equations of the form $(\frac{n}{a})! = b$?

Tags: diophantine-equations, factorial

I found myself today needing the natural solutions for $n$ satisfying this equation: 
$(\frac{n}{5})! = 2$

In this case I "got lucky" and was able to guess that 10 is a suitable solution.

Here are questions that popped in my mind:

1. Probably a trivial answer, but is this the only solution? If yes, how can we show it formally?
2. Perhaps a more interesting question: 
   given two constants $a,b \in \Bbb{N}$ , is there a way for calculating all Natural solutions for $n$ satisfying: $(\frac{n}{a})!=b$ 
   ?

Comment: How do you define the factorial of a fraction?  The usual technique is to use the Gamma function.  It values at non-integers also tend to be non-integral.  Given that, you are really solving for $\frac na$ in the integers.  There can only be one solution because factorial is monotonically increasing.

Comment: If $b$ is large, you can use the approx given by robjohn there https://math.stackexchange.com/a/2079043/399263, or the one by babler here https://math.stackexchange.com/a/432690/399263 based solely on log function (no W), else if $b$ small just use brute force.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$(n/a)!$ is (rapidly) increasing. So there can be at most one solution of $(n/a)!=b$ which can be easily found by checking $n=a, 2a,...$.

Comment: Wow nice! And how do I calculate it?

Comment: There is no faster method them simple checking.