# Simplifying Factorials to solve for a variable

Tags: discrete-mathematics, factorial

I was solving a problem in discrete math and i got the answer down to: 
$$26^8 = (n-7)(n-7)!$$ 
I was wondering how you would solve this for n, if that's even possible. Or do you think I made a mistake getting to this point?

Comment: Welcome to MSE. *How* did you get to that point?

Comment: Trying to find the length n of a string such that the expected number of occurrences of another string of length 8 found in the n-string is 1. The letters in the string are chosen at random

Answer (score 1):

Hint

Is it possible, if you are forcing $n$ to be a positive integer $\geq 7$?

$(26)^8$ is divisible by both $2$ and $13$, but is relatively prime to each of $3,5,7,11$.  Can a positive integer $m$, be found such that $m!$ satisfies these constraints?

Answer (score 0):

Making the problem more general, the problem is to find $n$ such that
$$(n-a)\,(n-a)!=k$$ where $k$ is a large number.

Making the *approximation* $(n-a)\,(n-a)!\sim (n-a+1)!$, we just need the inverse of the factorial.

On the site, @gary proposed a superb approximation of the inverse factorial (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430167/is-there-an-inverse-to-stirlings-approximation/461207#461207)). Applied to the problem, this will give
$$n \sim a+ \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{k}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)}}{{W\left( {\frac{1}{e}\log \left( {\frac{k}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)} \right)}} - \frac{1}{2}$$ where $W(.)$ is Lambert function.

Using $a=6$ and $k=26^8$ this would give,as an *approximation*
$n \sim 20.3242$ while the "exact" solution of your problem is $n=20.3521$