# Using Gosper's factorial approximation to determine the maximal $n$ in $n! = 2^p$

Tags: calculus, logarithms, recreational-mathematics, approximation, factorial

I'm trying to use the Gosper's factorial approximation to get a rough value of the maximal integer $n$ in $$n!\approx n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{\left(2n+\frac13\right)\pi} = 2^p$$ while avoiding to calculate the loop $F=\prod_{i=1}^{n}$ while $F$ is smaller than $2^p$ (and handling overflows). $p$ itself is a positive integer being a power of $2$.

This is for a computer algorithm that works with on integer lengths, that can be $p = 16$, $32$, $64$, $128$, $256$... ($p$ is a constant, known before the algorithm is evaluated, and is itself $p=2^b$, $b$ number of bits). The actual (unsigned) integer maximal value is actually $2^p-1$, but, to simplify, let's use $2^p$.

Starting from
$$n^ne^{-n}\sqrt{\left(2n+\frac13\right)\pi} = 2^p$$
I thought going with the (natural) $\log$ could be helpful
$$n\log(n)-n+\dfrac 12\log{\left((2n+\frac13)\pi\right)} = p\log (2)$$
but from here...

Maybe there is a better idea to approximate $n$ that costs less than $O(p)$? (approximation of the actual time complexity)

(Even if all $n$ values up to the max $b$ could be pre-calculated, let's assume the general case since we're on Math SE)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that it is simpler to just consider the equation in $n$
$$n!=2^p-1$$

For the inverse of the factorial function, @Gary proposed in year $2013$ a superb approximation (have a look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430167/is-there-an-inverse-to-stirlings-approximation/461207#461207)). Applied to your case, it will give
$$n \sim \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{2^p-1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)}}{{W\left( {\frac{1}{e}\log \left( {\frac{2^p-1}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)} \right)}} - \frac{1}{2}\tag 1$$ where $W(.)$ is [Lambert function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function). Up to you to decide if you want to use $\lceil n \rceil$ or $\lfloor n \rfloor$.

I give below the estimated value of $n$ as well as the exact solution for a few values of $p$

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
p & \text{estimate} & \text{solution} \\
  2 & 2.39249 &  2.40587 \\
 4 & 3.67329 &  3.68024 \\
 8 & 5.42819 &  5.43213 \\
 16 & 8.22333 &  8.22553 \\
 32 & 12.8558 &  12.8570 \\
 64 & 20.6665 &  20.6671 \\
 128 & 34.0398 &  34.0401 \\
 256 & 57.2588 &  57.2590 \\
 512 & 98.0766 &  98.0767 \\
 1024 & 170.624 &  170.624
\end{array}
\right)$$

If you do not have access to Lambert function, just approximate it using
$$W(t)\approx L_1-L_2+\frac{L_2}{L_1}+\frac{L_2(L_2-2)}{2L_1^2}+\frac{L_2(2L_2^2-9L_2+6)}{6L_1^3}+\cdots$$ where $L_1=\log(t)$ and $L_2=\log(L_1)$

**Edit**

If you want a real shortcut approximation, use for $p=2^k$
$$n = a + b \,k^c$$ A quick and dirty regression for $1 \leq k \leq 20$ (with $R^2=0.999994$)
$$\begin{array}{clclclclc}
 \text{} & \text{Estimate} & \text{Standard Error} & \text{Confidence Interval} \\
 a & 0.658561 & 0.004641 & \{0.649405,0.667716\} \\
 b & 0.261512 & 0.001185 & \{0.259174,0.263851\} \\
 c & 1.234300 & 0.001444 & \{1.231450,1.237150\} \\
\end{array}$$

Answer (score 1):

This is crazy over optimization, but it is fun so I will play along.  First, tabulate it for small $p$.  If we know $p$ is a power of $2$ we probably only need a dozen.  If we don't know that we might do a hundred.  Then we know that $n$ is rather large, so $n \gg \log(n) \gt 69$  Fixed point iteration will converge extremely quickly using
$$n= \frac 1{\log(n)}\left(p\log (2)+n-\dfrac 12\log{\left((2n+\frac13)\pi\right)} \right)$$
starting with (on the right) $n=\frac {p \log(2)}{69}\ \ \log(n)=69$ then calculating $n$ on the left and $\log(n)$ and plugging back into the right.