# How am I supposed to write the answer for this Alternating Series Estimation Theorem approximation?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

Here is the question:

[image]

Here is my work:

I substituted from n = 0 to n = 9
So, I got 1, -1, 0.5, -0.166, 0.0416, -0.0083, 0.00138, -0.000198, 0.0000248, -0.0000027.
Then, I added all these numbers together and got $$\frac{16687}{45360}$$
Once, I got that number, I set up my interval, which was:
$$\frac{16687}{45360} < S < \frac{16687}{45360} + 0.000005$$

That's my answer. Did I do it correctly or was I supposed to get an exact number?

Comment: How do you know $S<{16687\over45360}+0.000005$? Where did you get that $0.000005$ from?

Comment: @GerryMyerson I added the 5 x 10^-6 from the problem. I was following a khan academy video, but I probably misunderstood what he was saying.

Comment: The alternating series test implies that for any $N\geq 1$, $$
\sum\limits_{n = 0}^\infty  {( - 1)^n \frac{1}{{n!}}}  = \sum\limits_{n = 0}^{N - 1} {( - 1)^n \frac{1}{{n!}}}  + \varepsilon _N ,
$$ where $$
\left| {\varepsilon _N } \right| \le \frac{1}{{N!}}.
$$ You need to choose $N$ so that $\left| {\varepsilon _N } \right| \leq 5\cdot 10^{-6}$. The above estimate for $\left| {\varepsilon _N } \right| $ helps you to find such an $N$.

Comment: @Gary I'm not sure... I thought n = 9 was the maximum, but now I'm confused about how to solve this. Do I not use n = 10?

Comment: $N=9$ is the smallest value for which $\frac{1}{N!}\leq 5\cdot 10^{-6}$. So you can take $N=9$, i.e., the last term kept in the series is $\frac{1}{8!}$. Of course any larger $N$ would work as well, but you do not want to have too many terms.

Comment: Just by curiosity, have a look at the superb approximation @Gary gave in https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430167/is-there-an-inverse-to-stirlings-approximation/461207#461207

Comment: @Gary So, rather than adding 5 * 10^-6, would I take the value of n = 9? Edit: Alright I'll check it out

Comment: The task is to figure out how many terms you have to keep so that their sum approximates the sum of the infinite series by an absolute error that is less than $5\cdot 10^{-6}$. The approximation is $$
1 - 1 +  \cdots  + \frac{1}{{8!}} = \frac{{2119}}{{5760}}.
$$I feel that you did not completely understand the various concepts here.

Comment: @Gary Yeah, I'm not really sure how to do this. We just started learning this week. I've been looking at different pdfs but they all seem confusing. How did you get 2119/5760? Did I get some parts right, like about adding the numbers I listed?

Comment: I think you added $-1/9!$ as well. That is why your rational approximation is different. But as I noted you do not have to go up to $-1/9!$ in order to get the required accuracy.