# Solving $n!=x$ for $n$.

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, factorial, lambert-w

Trying to solve / approximate for $n$ in
$$n!=x\tag 1$$
where $x$ is given, I started with Stirling's approximation

$$n!\approx\sqrt{2\pi n}(n/e)^n\tag 2$$

Taking log and divide by $e$:

$$\frac1{2e}\ln(2\pi n)+\frac ne\ln(n/e)\approx \frac1e\ln x \tag3$$

Now in order to proceed, I neglected the left term with $\ln(2\pi n)$ and took the 0-th branch of Lambert $W$ assuming $x$ is large:

$$\ln n - 1 = \ln(n/e) = W(\tfrac ne\ln(n/e))\approx W(\tfrac1e\ln x) \tag4$$

Finally, adding $1$ and taking $\exp$ yields the approximation

$$n \approx \exp\left(1+W\Big(\frac1e\ln x\Big)\right) \tag5$$

That approximation is not too bad, but the results are too big by ca. 0.7 for bigger numbers; for example $x=100!$ yields $n\approx 100.7$.

**Question:** Is there a way to improve the result? For example, something that's smarter than just throwing away $\ln(2\pi n)$ in $(3)$.

I tried to find a better approximation of $\sum_k \ln k$ but all I found was solutions that effectively referred back to Stirling's $(2)$.

---

That linked question doen't answer my question. First, it doesn't explain how to improve my calculation; and my question is about improving my calculation.  Second, the term +0.5 is coming out of the blue and without explanation, except that it's "good". So no, that answer didn't help. In particular I don't seek for sites to copy-paste from, I am striving to getting better technique etc.

---

I checked that other answer again and i still **does not explain where the 0.5 is coming from.  It just asserts that value from the start and claims it it "good" starting with it.**

Comment: The formula by Robjohn [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/2078997/399263) might be more accurate.

Comment: It's also been addressed in [this MO post](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/12828/inverse-gamma-function), but some sources are a bit outdated.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is there an inverse to Stirling's approximation?](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430167/is-there-an-inverse-to-stirlings-approximation)

Comment: No, and I explained why in the question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> something that's smarter than just throwing away $\ln(2πn)$ in $(3)$

Taking up the comments, the first idea is to divide out $\sqrt{2\pi}$ from the start so that $(3)$ becomes:

$$\frac1{2e}\ln(n)+\underbrace{\frac ne\ln(n/e)}_{\textstyle=:f(n)}\approx \frac1e\ln\frac x{\sqrt{2\pi}} \tag{3'}$$

Second idea is to set $f(n) = \dfrac ne\ln(n/e)$ and to find $\Delta$ such that

$$f(n+\Delta)\approx f(n) + \Delta f'(n) \approx f(n) + \frac 1{2e}\ln n\tag{*}$$

i.e. one adds some amout $\Delta$ to the argument of $f$ such that it accounts for the term $(\ln n)/(2e)$ in the LHS of $(3')$ that was previously neglected. Solving $(*)$ for $\Delta$ gives:

$$\begin{align}
\Delta \approx \frac{\ln n}{2e\cdot f'(n)} 
= \frac{\ln n}{2e\cdot\Big(\dfrac1e(1+\ln (n/e))\Big)} = \frac12\\
\end{align}$$

This turns $(3')$ into

$$\frac1{2e}\ln(n)+\frac ne\ln(n/e)
\approx \frac {n+0.5}e\ln\frac {n+0.5}e
\approx \frac1e\ln\frac x{\sqrt{2\pi}} \tag{3"}$$
The rest of the derivation is the same: Apply Lambert $W$:

$$\ln\frac {n+0.5}e \approx W\left(\frac1e\ln\frac x{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right) \tag{4'}$$
and finally solve for $n$:

$$\bbox[10px,border:1px solid]{n \approx \exp\left(1+W\left(\frac1e\ln\frac x{\sqrt{2\pi}}\right)\right) -\frac12 }\tag{5'}$$

The results are much more precise now, for example:

$$3! \mapsto 2.9905$$

$$100! \mapsto 99.99991$$

which is perfectly fine for my purposes.

Comment: $\Delta = 1/2$ makes me think of the [continuity correction](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Continuity_correction). I wonder if there's a connection that can be drawn.

Comment: Related to [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461207) old answer of mine.

Comment: You can “unaccept” your self answer since you are looking for one explaining the “0.5”

Comment: Tyma Gaidash: Now I am totally confused. My question was proposed for close because there is some other question with similar content. That other answer starts with claiming out of the blue that $((n+0.5)/e)^{n+0.5}$ is good; where from Stirling you'll get $n^{n+0.5}/e^n$. In my answer I worked out how the term $+0.5$ gets involved, and my result turned out the same like from the other answer.   I didn't even read that other answer because it is useless without explanation or derivation.  So what did I do wrong now?