# An inverse factorial approximation

Tags: functional-analysis, functions, solution-verification, proof-explanation, inverse-function

A few days ago, I found this weird inverse factorial approximation for complex numbers mostly between 1 and 24. The approximation is $\sqrt{5\ln\left(x+\frac{1}{5}\right)}$.

Here are a few values with this function

$f\left(1\right)=0.9547815373$, **actual value = 1**

$f\left(2\right)=1.98551927763$, **actual value = 2**

$f\left(3\right)=2.41158745415$, **actual value ≈ 2.40586998631**

$f\left(6\right)=3.02038846181$, **actual value = 3**

$f\left(12\right)=3.53654913138$, **actual value ≈ 3.52239790956**

$f\left(24\right)=3.99146128201$, **actual value = 4**

The approximation later diverges, but would you know how this function might be derived? And if it can't, could someone explain what this has to do with factorials?

Comment: This may be useful: https://math.stackexchange.com/q/461207

Comment: The equivalent statement is $$
n! \approx \mathrm{e}^{n^2 /5}  - \frac{1}{5}
$$ for $1\leq n\leq 4$.