# Solving for $x$, $e^x=x!$

Tags: asymptotics, exponential-function, special-functions, factorial, gamma-function

I am curious on where the factorial $x!=\Gamma(x+1)$ passes the exponential $e^x$ for $x>0$. I first tried using Lambert $W$ and the [inverse of Stirling's approximation](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/461207/1141581) by @Gary. Call $p$ the point at which the factorial passes the exponential.
$$p=e^x\ \text{and}\ p=x!$$
The first can easily be evaluated as $x=\log(p)$ and using the Lambert $W$ function, the latter is (work by Gary) $$x = \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{p}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)}}{{W\left( {\frac{1}{e}\log \left( {\frac{p}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)} \right)}} - \frac{1}{2} $$ for sufficiently large $p$. Equating the two we obtain,
$$\log(p) = \frac{{\log \left( {\frac{p}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)}}{{W\left( {\frac{1}{e}\log \left( {\frac{p}{{\sqrt {2\pi } }}} \right)} \right)}} - \frac{1}{2}$$
but I can't continue further. I tried using the gamma function as well but failed to come up with anything significant. Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: $x=0$ obviously works

Comment: Other than that, not everything has a closed form. The largest real solution is between $5$ and $6,$ but I'd be surprised if there was a closed form.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews. You are right, that will work. I am curious of the other intersection though.

Comment: [Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=e%5Ex%3DGamma%28x%2B1%29) gives about $5.2903$ as a numeric result.  It doesn't offer an exact form.

Comment: @RossMillikan. I've observed that too. I guess if wolfram can't find it, there probably is no closed form?

Comment: It isn't a guarantee-there might be an approach it missed, but it is a good indication.

Comment: You can try Newton's method with $x_0=\ln200$ and $f(x)=\frac{e^{x}}{x!}-1$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you look [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1333449/could-this-approximation-be-made-simpler-solve-n-an-10k), you will find a superb approximation built by @robjohn. Applied to your problem
$$x!=e^x \qquad \implies \qquad \color{blue}{x\sim \exp\left(2+ W\left(-\frac{\log (2 e \pi )}{2 e^2}\right)\right)-\frac 12}$$ which is $5.28081$ that is to say in a relative error of $0.18$%.

Now, using Newton-like methods of order $n$ for finding the zero of function
$$f(x)=\log(x!)-x$$, the first iteration is still explicit and easy to obtain since
$$\big[\log(x!)]^{(n)}=\psi ^{(n-1)}(x+1)$$

So, the results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
 n & \text{first estimate} & \text{method} \\
 2 & \color{red}{5.2903}264120457478491 & \text{Newton} \\
 3 & \color{red}{5.2903160}763059627349 & \text{Halley} \\
 4 & \color{red}{5.2903160931}486923581 & \text{Householder} \\
 5 & \color{red}{5.2903160931197}199474 & \text{no name} \\
 6 & \color{red}{5.290316093119770}8007 & \text{no name} \\
 7 & \color{red}{5.290316093119770710}6 & \text{no name} \\
\cdots & \cdots & \\
\infty & \color{red}{5.2903160931197707107} & \text{solution} \\
\end{array}
\right)$$ showing for the absolute error
$$\log_{10}(|\text{error}|_n)=0.5158964 - 2.760374 \,n$$ Notice that the slope is $\sim -e$.

**Edit**

Making the problem more general
$$x!=e^{k x}\qquad \implies \qquad \large\color{blue}{x_{(k)}\sim \exp\left(k+1 +W\left(-\frac {k+\log (2 \pi ) }{2 e^{k+1} }\right)\right)-\frac 12}$$

Some results
$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k &  \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 5.28080609982 &  5.29031609313 \\
 2 & 17.5609484230 &  17.5635286436 \\
 3 & 51.6222027742 &  51.6230410442 \\
 4 & 144.964737552 &  144.965029854 \\
 5 & 399.495201639 &  399.495306705 \\
 6 & 1092.20718395 &  1092.20722222 \\
 7 & 2976.03576673 &  2976.03578075 \\
 8 & 8097.66349482 &  8097.66349997 \\
 9 & 22020.5461895 &  22020.5461914 \\
 10 & 59867.7224841 &  59867.7224841 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

For $k=10$, the absolute error is $6.96\times 10^{-7}\qquad \color{red}{\large \text{(!!)}}$

Asymptotically,
$$x_{(k+1)} \sim e\,x_{(k)}$$ which is already clear looking at the numbers in the table.

Comment: I wonder if Lagrange inversion can be used here too. (+1)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. The link takes me to Gary's answer. Where can I find @robjohn's?

Comment: @bob. Sorry ! It has been fixed. For the fun, look at the edit. Cheers :-)

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. That's some impressive results! Always appreciate your work Claude. Cheers!

Comment: @bob. Thanks for the nice words but I did not do anything beside using robjohn superb approximation. Cheers & thanks for the nice problem.

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. If I may ask, what software do you use to compute these values? The calculators I use have no where near the accuracy you obtain.

Comment: @bob. Which values ?

Comment: @ClaudeLeibovici. For example, 

$$\left(
\begin{array}{ccc}
k &  \text{approximation} & \text{solution} \\
 1 & 5.28080609982 &  5.29031609313 \\
 2 & 17.5609484230 &  17.5635286436 \\
 3 & 51.6222027742 &  51.6230410442 \\
 4 & 144.964737552 &  144.965029854 \\
 5 & 399.495201639 &  399.495306705 \\
 6 & 1092.20718395 &  1092.20722222 \\
 7 & 2976.03576673 &  2976.03578075 \\
 8 & 8097.66349482 &  8097.66349997 \\
 9 & 22020.5461895 &  22020.5461914 \\
 10 & 59867.7224841 &  59867.7224841 \\
\end{array}
\right)$$

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/145026/discussion-between-claude-leibovici-and-bob).

Answer (score 1):

Though an analytical solution can't be given, an approximate solution using the Lambert $W$ function can be derived by following the general steps taken by @robjohn. Start by using a slightly modified version of Stirling's formula, $\log(x!)\sim x\log(x)-x+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi x)$.
$$\begin{align*}
\log\left(\frac{e^x}{x!}\right) & \sim x-\left(x\log(x)-x+\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi x)\right) \\ &
=2x-x\log(x)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi x) \\ &
=-x\log\left(\frac{x}{e^2}\right)-\frac{1}{2}\log(2\pi x)
\end{align*}$$ To solve the equation above for $x$ using the Lambert $W$, first multiply both sides by $-1/e^2$ to get,
$$\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{e^2}\log{\left(\frac{e^x}{x!}\right)}\sim\frac{x}{e^2}\log{\left(\frac{x}{e^2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2e^2}\log(2\pi x)
\end{align*}$$then subtracting $\frac{1}{2e^2}\log\left(2\pi e^2\right)$,
$$\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{e^2}\log{\left(\frac{e^x}{x!}\right)}-\frac{1}{2e^2}\log\left(2\pi e^2\right)&\sim\frac{x}{e^2}\log{\left(\frac{x}{e^2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2e^2}\log(2\pi x)-\frac{1}{2e^2}\log\left(2\pi e^2\right) \\
-\frac{1}{e^{2}}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{x+1}}{x!}\right)&\sim\frac{x}{e^2}\log{\left(\frac{x}{e^2}\right)}+\frac{1}{2e^2}\log\left(\frac{x}{e^2}\right) \\
&=\frac{2x+1}{2e^2}\log\left(\frac{x}{e^2}\right) \\
&\sim \frac{2x+1}{2e^2}\log\left(\frac{2x+1}{2e^2}\right)-\frac{1}{2e^2}
\end{align*}$$hence, we end up with a form which can be expressed with the Lambert $W$ function, defined as $z=W(z)e^{W(z)}$ for $z>0$. $$\begin{align*}
-\frac{1}{e^2}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{x+1/2}}{x!}\right)&\sim\frac{2x+1}{2e^2}\log\left(\frac{2x+1}{2e^2}\right) \\
&=\log\left(\frac{2x+1}{2e^2}\right)\exp\left(\log\left(\frac{2x+1}{2e^2}\right)\right)
\end{align*}$$Applying the [Lambert $W$ function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lambert_W_function) and solving for $x$, $$x\sim e^2\exp\left(W\left(-\frac{1}{e^2}\log\left(\frac{\sqrt{2\pi}e^{x+1/2}}{x!}\right)\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2}$$substituting $\log\left(e^x/x!\right)=0$ yields the final expression,$${x\sim e^2\exp\left(W\left(-\frac{\log\left({2\pi e}\right)}{2e^2}\right)\right)-\frac{1}{2}}.$$