Approximating Euler's number to a certain decimal point
Question:
What methods or formulas do you know, which can tell you  how accurate $s_N=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\frac{1}{k!}$ is approximating Euler's number to a given decimal place $n$?
my attempt:
Let $N \in \mathbb{N}$ then consider $N!e=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{\infty}\frac{N!}{k!}$, which can be rewritten as $$N!e=N!(\overbrace{\sum\limits_{k=0}^{N}\frac{1}{k!}}^{s_N}+\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{k!})\iff N!(e-s_N)=\sum\limits_{k=N+1}^{\infty}\frac{N!}{k!}=\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\prod\limits_{m=1}^{k}(N+m)^{-1}\\<\sum\limits_{k=1}^{\infty}\frac{1}{(N+1)^k}=\frac{\frac{1}{N+1}}{1-\frac{1}{N+1}}=\frac{1}{N}.$$
Now dividing by $N!$ we get $e-s_N<\frac{1}{NN!}$. Then by solving the equation $NN!=10^n$ and taking the ceiling of the resulting $N$, we should optain a value which at least gives us $n$ accurate digits.
I have testet this formula for small values of $n$ and it seemes to be quite precise, but i dont know wether or not this trend continuous for larger values of $n$. Besides that there is the problem of evaluating the found equation. One could further reduce the approximation by the fact that $\frac{1}{NN!}\leq\frac{1}{N!}$, but this still leaves us with the nasty factorial. Maybe you could get a shot at solving this by using the gamma function or the stirling-approximation, but that doenst seem to improve the situation much further.

The most straightforward method (assuming you know the following fact) is to look at the formula for the remainder at the Taylor's series: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Taylor%27s_theorem#Explicit_formulas_for_the_remainder

Your $e-s_N<\frac{1}{N,N!}\le\frac{1}{N!}$ is correct.  There is a slight issue over rounding, so it may be wise to check that adding $\frac{1}{N!}$ cannot change the final digit of your approximation, by calculating a few extra digits and using a slightly larger $N$.   As for solving your equation, you might also want to note that if $n!=k$ then $\frac{\ln(k)}{\ln(\ln(k))} < n < 2\frac{\ln(k)}{\ln(\ln(k))}$ when $n \ge 4$ i.e. when $k\ge 24$, which at least puts some loose bounds on what you are looking for.

@njuffa: good point: "seel" is a word that often comes up in English word puzzles. It is not a cheery word, either in the sense of sowing closed the eyelids of a raptor for training purposes, or in the sense of closing the eyes of a corpse. (Apologies for making what must be the MSE comment with the least mathematical content of all time!)

If you want to solve for $n$ the equation
$$n,n!=10^k$$ consider instead, to make life easier
$$(n+1)!=10^k$$ and use https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/430167/is-there-an-inverse-to-stirlings-approximation/461207#461207 where@Gary gave an almost exact solution.

$$S_n=\sum\limits_{k=0}^{n}\frac{1}{k!}=e\,\frac{ \Gamma (n+1,1)}{\Gamma (n+1)}$$ If $n$ is large
$$\Delta_n=e-S_n \sim \frac{e^n\, n^{-n-\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{2
   \pi }}$$ and we want that $\Delta_n\leq 10^{-k}$. Looking at the equality, taking logarithms, we need to solve for $n$
$$n-\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \log (n)=\log(10^{-k}\sqrt{2
   \pi })$$ what we can rewrite as
$$\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)-\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \log (n)=\frac 32+\log(10^{-k}\sqrt{2\pi })=C$$
Assuming that
$$\log(n) \sim \log\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right)$$ we have the solution in terms of Lambert function
$$n \sim -\frac{C}{W\left(-\frac{C}{e}\right)}-\frac{3}{2}$$ which is an underestimate of the solution.
For example, if $k=10$, the above gives,as a real, $n=11.6022$ while the "exact" solution is $12.2142$.
This can be improved writing
$$n-\left(n+\frac{3}{2}\right) \log (n)\sim (n+a)-(n+a)\log(n+a)-a$$ Computing the infinite norm between $n=10$ and $n=100$ gives an optimum value $a\sim \frac 65$ and the solution write
$$n \sim -\frac{C}{W\left(-\frac{C}{e}\right)}-\frac{6}{5}\quad \text{where} \quad C=\frac 65+\log(10^{-k}\sqrt{2\pi })$$ which is an underestimate of the solution.
If $k=10$, the above gives,as a real, $n=12.0186$ while the "exact" solution is $12.2142$.
We can also consider that we want to find the zero of function
$$f(n)=\log \left(10^k\,\frac{e^n n^{-n-\frac{3}{2}}}{\sqrt{2 \pi
   }}\right)$$ Using $n_0=k$, the first iterate of Newton method is
$$\color{blue}{n_1=k-\frac{k}{2 k \log (k)+3}\,\log\Bigg(2\pi k^3 \left(\frac{k}{10\, e}\right)^{2 k}\Bigg)}$$ which, for $k=10$ gives $n=12.2944$.
The estimate is good because, if
$$f^{(1)}(k)=-\frac{3}{2 k}-\log (k)$$ is large
$$ f^{(2)}(k)=\frac{3-2 k}{2 k^2}\quad  f^{(3)}(k)=\frac{k-3}{k^3}\quad  f^{(4)}(k)=\frac{9-2 k}{k^4}$$ are smaller and smaller.
Taking into account this last point, the first iterate of Halley method gives a slightly more complex formula which for $k=10$ would give $n=12.2032$.
If we continue the expansion, using
$$a=\log \left(\frac{e^k k^{-k-\frac{3}{2}}
   10^k}{\sqrt{2 \pi }}\right)\quad \text{and}\quad b=2 k \log (k)+3$$
$$n=k+\frac{2 a k}{b}-\frac{2 a^2 (k (2k-3))}{b^3}+\cdots$$
